# Is there a way to tell git to only include certain files instead of ignoring certain files?

Tags: git, gitignore

My programs generally generate huge output files (~1 GB) which I do not want to be backing up to the git repository.  So instead of being able to do

```
git add .
```

I have to do something like

```
git add *.c *.cc *.f *.F *.C *.h *.cu
```

which is a little bit cumbersome...

I feel fairly confident I could write a quicky perl script ls the directory contents into .gitignore and then remove files based on a .gitinclude (or some similar name) file, but that seems a little too hackish.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

I haven't had need to try this myself, but from my reading of [TFM](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) it looks like a negated pattern would do what you want. You can override entries in .gitignore with later negated entries. Thus you could do something like:

```
*.c
!frob_*.c
!custom.c
```

To have it ignore all .c files except custom.c and anything starting with "frob_"

Comment: Thanks, T.E.D.  This worked.  All I had to do was start the .gitignore file with * and then list all of my included file patterns proceeded by an exclamation point.

Comment: How about folders? I cant find a way to include folders and files inside by negating a rule.

Comment: About folders please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799855/configure-git-to-track-only-one-file-extension

Comment: very nice. I am using this to have a repository in my home folder for things like vimrc and bashrc

Comment: @uzsolt does not work if you want to include one specific folder. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files/29932318#29932318

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko - Well, a decade ago when I wrote this, "RTFM" was a pretty typical response online to questions with a reference answer, and the phrase was so ubiquitous that between techies it wasn't even considered particularly rude. People often applied it to themselves (as I did here). These days I don't think I'd necessarily throw that in there...

Comment: I don't think it hurts sometimes. I run my own blog and the only time I create an article is if I can't find the answer or it wasn't obvious. Usually RTFM or TFM applies - people like to ask before they look it up. Either way I like your reply.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with folders. I'm trying to include a specific path to a file, after its upper-level folder has been ignored, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ShimmyWeitzhandler - Try reading the comments about 5 above yours.

Comment: After restarting VS things are working now. It was something inside the `.vs` folder, so it's understandable. Thank you.

Comment: For my case only `!**/my-folder/build` worked. Remember to reapply `.gitignore` as needed.

Answer (score 95):

create .gitignore file in your repository and you want to track only c files and ignore all other files then add the following lines to it....

```
*
!*.c
```

'*' will ignore all files

and ! will negate files be to ignored....so here we are asking git not to ignore c files....

Comment: Do you also need `.*` for hidden files?

Comment: The `*` is a wildcard even for `.`, so hidden files are also ignored, but then all hidden files ending in `.c` are included.

Comment: Using this method I think files from subfolders are also ignored. Check this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/11853075/739436

Comment: I used this method in my home directory to only track my .bashrc and .bash_history e.g. 

`*` followed by 
`!.bash*` in the .gitignore file

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You might need `*.*` on windows - see the answer by @Smaranjit Maiti

Comment: agree with @popas. "man gitignore" states that "An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a           previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded."

Comment: if you have *.c in subdirectories, havin ga * as the first directory, effectively ignores allsubdirectories. So even you include a !*.c after *, the files in the subdirectories wont be included.

Comment: yep, `*` does not work with my Git version on Windows...only `*.*` works

Answer (score 23):

> **The best solution to achieve this**

create **`.gitignore`** file in repository **`root`**, and if you want to include only **`.c`** file then you need to add below lines to **`.gitignore`** file

```
*.*
!*.c
```

this will include all **`.c`** file from directory and subdirectory recursively.

*using*

```
*
!*.c
```

*will not work on all version of git.*

> Tested on
>
> git version 2.12.2.windows.2

Comment: Yes I had the same problem with `*`, and had to use `*.*`. This is on Windows using gitbash and git version 2.9.0.windows.1

Answer (score 16):

If you need to ignore files but not a specific file inside a directory, here is how I did it:

```
# Ignore everything under "directory"
directory/*
# But don't ignore "another_directory"
!directory/another_directory
# But ignore everything under "another_directory"
directory/another_directory/*
# But don't ignore "file_to_be_staged.txt"
!directory/another_directory/file_to_be_staged.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

I've seen a number of suggestions for the initial "ignore everything" rule, both here on SO and on other sites, but I found most of them to have thir own annoying usage issues. this has given rise to projects like [the distributable `.gitinclude.NET`](https://github.com/gitinclude/gitinclude.NET) and the [GH Pages hosted `git-do-not-ignore`](https://github.com/theapache64/git-do-not-ignore), each of which simply help make this less tedious to manutain.

each of these (and many other blog posts) recommend starting out with a simply `*` to, quite literally, ignore all files and folders in the current root.

thereafter, *including* a file is "as simple" as prefixing the path with `!`, such as `!.gitignore` to ensure our repo doesn't ignore it's own `.gitignore` rules file.

the down side of this, is that when Git encounters an ignored folder, for performance reasons it does not check it's contents. trying to *not* ignore a file in a nested path gets very cumbersome:

```
# ...when ignoring all files and folders in the current root
*

!custom_path                       # allow Git to look inside this folder
custom_path/*                      # but ignore everything it contains
!custom_path/extras                # allow Git to look inside this folder
custom_path/extras/*               # but ignore everything it contains
!custom_path/extras/path_to_keep   # allow Git to see the file or folder you want to commit
```

---

so to offer an alternative idea, I've just configured a `.gitignore` file in the root of my Windows user profile folder, starting with `**/*` instead of the commonly seen `*` or `*.*`.

thereafter, each path that I want to explicitly include requires only one entry *per tree level*. *slightly* simplifying the previous example to the following:

```
# ...when ignoring all files recursively from the current root
**/*

!custom_path                       # allow Git to look inside this folder
!custom_path/extras                # allow Git to look inside this folder
!custom_path/extras/path_to_keep   # allow Git to see the file or folder you want to commit
```

this is not exactly a **massive** difference, but it is enough of a difference to make the file much easier to read and maintain, especially when trying to "un-ignore" a file nested about 5 levels deep...

Comment: The problem with this method is that you can't unignore directories, only individual files (unless I'm missing something)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only trying to include dot files, this worked for me...

```
!.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but my solution would be to have a directory for source files and a different directory for executables and program output, something like this:

```
+ .git
|    (...)
+ bin
|    my_exe.exe
|    my_output.txt
+ src
     some_file.c
     some_file.h
```

... and then only add the stuff in `src/` to my repository and ignore `bin/` entirely.