# How to include only selected files into git repository and exclude all the rest?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there any chance to do an opposite to what .gitignore file does? I mean include only specified files and exclude all the rest? Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to tell git to only include certain files instead of ignoring certain files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279533/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-to-only-include-certain-files-instead-of-ignoring-cert)

Comment: Some of the other related questions are duplicates too, and there are even more out there...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
#ignore everything
*

#except .c source
!*.c
```

(`!` negates the patterns specified in gitignore)

Comment: an ignore on * would have been enough. Here a README file would still be versioned

Answer (score -2):

if you want to concern only one folder in root try this:

```
# ignore everything
*
# except .gitignore file
!.gitignore
# except my folder
!concered_folder_name
!concered_folder_name/*
```