# How can I configure Checkstyle in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, configuration, checkstyle

I am using Maven.

I have a parent module and some other modules.

They look like this:

```
PARENT
├── pom.xml
├── ModulA
|   └── pom.xml
└── ModulB
    ├── pom.xml
    └── folder
        └── checkstyle.xml
```

I tried to replace the rules with my own rules. But it ignores my rules. I added the plug-in to parent pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
        <configLocation>
            ${basedir}/../ModulB/folder/checkstyle.xml                  
        </configLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Where is the problem?

### **EDIT:**

The result of `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -X`:

```xml
...
    <configuration>
      <cacheFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/checkstyle-cachefile"/>
      <configLocation default-value="config/sun_checks.xml">${checkstyle.config.location}</configLocation>
      <consoleOutput default-value="false"/>
      <enableFilesSummary default-value="true">${checkstyle.enable.files.summary}</enableFilesSummary>
      <enableRSS default-value="true">${checkstyle.enable.rss}</enableRSS>
      <enableRulesSummary default-value="true">${checkstyle.enable.rules.summary}</enableRulesSummary>
      <enableSeveritySummary default-value="true">${checkstyle.enable.severity.summary}</enableSeveritySummary>
      <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
      <excludes>${checkstyle.excludes}</excludes>
      <failsOnError default-value="false"/>
      <format default-value="sun"/>
      <headerFile>${basedir}/LICENSE.txt</headerFile>
      <headerLocation default-value="LICENSE.txt">${checkstyle.header.file}</headerLocation>
      <includeTestSourceDirectory default-value="${false}"/>
      <includes default-value="**/*.java">${checkstyle.includes}</includes>
      <linkXRef default-value="true">${linkXRef}</linkXRef>
      <outputDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
      <outputFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/checkstyle-result.xml">${checkstyle.output.file}</outputFile>
      <outputFileFormat default-value="xml">${checkstyle.output.format}</outputFileFormat>
      <project default-value="${project}"/>
      <propertiesLocation>${checkstyle.properties.location}</propertiesLocation>
      <skip default-value="false">${checkstyle.skip}</skip>
      <sourceDirectory default-value="${project.build.sourceDirectory}"/>
      <suppressionsFileExpression default-value="checkstyle.suppressions.file">${checkstyle.suppression.expression}</suppressionsFileExpression>
      <suppressionsLocation>${checkstyle.suppressions.location}</suppressionsLocation>
      <testSourceDirectory default-value="${project.build.testSourceDirectory}"/>
      <xrefLocation default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/xref"/>
    </configuration>
...
```

Comment: When does it ignore your rules : mvn checkstyle:checktyle or your IDE ? on all modules ?

Comment: @yodamad Yes, on all modules..

Comment: @yodamad I don't know how to write the path to checkstyle.xml

Answer (score 15):

For it to pick up your custom configuration, you need to declare your file as a property:

```
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...

  <properties>
    <checkstyle.config.location><!-- file location --></checkstyle.config.location>
  </properties>

  <build>
    ...

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Taken from my tutorial on how to create a custom CheckStyle check here:
http://blog.blundellapps.com/create-your-own-checkstyle-check/

Source code here:
https://github.com/blundell/CreateYourOwnCheckStyleCheck

Comment: You're right. The official docs at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/ and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html say that you need to use the configLocation parameter to configure this, but that didn't work for me, whereas setting the <checkstyle.config.location> property works nicely. Thank you.

Comment: I was pulling my hair when I finally realized that what @GlennLawrence is true!

Answer (score 5):

Why you don't put your checkstyle config in a directory in parent project like `src/main/resources` and parametrized the plugin in parent pom.xml like this

```
<!-- Checkstyle -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>src/main/resources/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>                   
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Child projects should have access do this configuration

Comment: It is the project structure. All configuration files are in ModulB

Comment: Ok, so you can try this variable `${project.parent.basedir}` instead of `${basedir}`

Comment: If you keep your original configuration and just replace `${basedir}/../ModulB/folder/checkstyle.xml` by `${project.parent.basedir}/../ModulB/folder/checkstyle.xml`.

Comment: Arf. When do you get the problem : in your IDE on sources or in mvn checkstyle:checkstyle execution while generating CS report ?

Comment: I execute mvn checkstyle:checkstyle on parent pom or on module poms

Comment: There's a mistake in my previous post, path should be `${project.parent.basedir}/ModulB/folder/checkstyle.xml`

Comment: Maven ignores everything that i write as path info.

Comment: Weird. Can you post your complete pom.xml ? And your plugin version seems quite old, try to update to latest one (2.9.1). Then run `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle -X` to get verbose information

Comment: Information like : `Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.9.1:checkstyle' with basic configurator -->
   (f) configLocation = config/sun_checks.xml` or `request.getConfigLocation() config/sun_checks.xml`