# gitignore - only allow certain extensions and files

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm using the following code to ignore all files except for certain filenames and extension

```
*
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
!readme.md
!.gitkeep
!*.php
```

For some reason, its only allowing me to commit the .gitignore and readme.md, even though I have php files in subfolders etc. Is there anything wrong with it? Just fyi, I'm using "git add -A" to pick up the files to commit.

Comment: the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606028/382515) worked for me, adding `!.gitignore` at the end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to tell git to only include certain files instead of ignoring certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279533/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-to-only-include-certain-files-instead-of-ignoring-cer)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The solution is to tell Git **not to ignore sub directories**:

```
*
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
!readme.md
!.gitkeep
!*.php
!*/
```

Otherwise, only the `*.php` files in the first directory level will be accepted and all sub directories will be ignored.

Comment: Use *.*. Having a * at the top will exclude any *.php files that are in subdirectories. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: I have to move the `!*/` line to just after the `*` to make this work

Answer (score 17):

> The most sophisticated method to achieve this

create **`.gitignore`** file in repository **`root`**, and add below lines to **`.gitignore`** file

```
*.*
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
!readme.md
!.gitkeep
!*.php
```

this will include all specified file from directory and subdirectory recursively.

tested on

> git version 2.12.2.windows.2

Comment: I like this answer better than the accepted one because it works beyond just one level of recursion

Comment: This approach fails to ignore files with no extension

Comment: @ojchase indeed, but it still solves my personal use-case fully, as I can add appropriate endings if a file pops up that shouldn't be tracked.