# Can I use gitignore to only include files with certain extensions, recursively?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'd like to only include files with certain extensions, from a complex directory tree.

Solutions presented [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11852558/207655) do not work for this specific use case, since they stop at one level or something like that.

Is that possible?

That is, as an alternative of just creating a script that does `find` and `git add` manually them one by one.

Comment: The accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11853075/7976758 at the linked question is the solution. It even states "*Otherwise, only the `*.php` files in the first directory level will be accepted and all sub directories will be ignored.*"