# Configure git to track only one file extension

Tags: git, file-extension, gitignore, subdirectory

I have one directory tree with many kind of different files. There are 300 directories on the parent directory. Each directory could have other sub directories.

I only want to track *.cocci on all sub directories. Here is my .gitignore:

```
*
!*.cocci
```

But it do not work, as the files on sub directories are not tracked. How can I tell git that I only want to track *.cocci on all sub directories?

Comment: Have you actually `git add`ed the files? Just setting up `.gitignore` does not automatically cause files to be tracked...

Comment: I can only add a file if I use git add -f <file>. This do not seem correct...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whitelisting and subdirectories in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/whitelisting-and-subdirectories-in-git)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162919/git-whitelisting-files-in-a-complex-directory-structure/9227991#comment17298028_9227991).

You want:

```
# Blacklist everything
*
# Whitelist all directories
!*/
# Whitelist the file you're interested in. 
!*.cocci
```

Note, this'll track **only** `*.cocci` files. Yours doesn't work because you ignore **everything** (that's the first line), which ignores *all subdirectories*.

Comment: I'm still not happy with git status output as it do not show untracked folder contents but the filter is working now. Thanks

Comment: Could you please change the comments in your answer? They must start their own lines. If you paste this into a .gitignore, it will not work (tested on v.1.9.1). Check out http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Ignoring-Files

Comment: You may also want to whitelist .gitignore

Answer (score 7):

To extend @simont answer, if we wanted to whitelist  `*.cocci` files of a given directory and its subdirectories I would wrongly have entered:

```
directory/*
!directory/*/
!directory/*.cocci
```

That seems not to be including `*.cocci` files under `directory/subtree`.

In order to find all `*.cocci` files in all sub-directories of `directory` entered the following:

```
directory/**
!directory/*/
!directory/**/*.cocci
```

Comment: Great! That's what I was finding! To make it clearer, if I want to ignore everything other than `./directory/*`, I should put `*; !directory/; !directory/*`.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to unignore directory by `!dir` in .gitignore, but then it is still possible to add directory by hand:

```
git add dir -f
```

So if the .gitignore file looks like:

```
*
!*.txt
```

Then when you do `git add .` new `*.txt` files are then added. New directory will not be auto-added, it have to be added by  hand by `git add dir -f`

Comment: This solved my issue with a directory that was being ignored, even though my `.gitignore` file had a `!dir/.exists` file setup. Note that the `dir` in the answer above should be replaced with the name of the directory that you want to be included in the git checkin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `!*/*.cocci` instead of your `!*.cocci`?