# Netbeans with GitHub commit only selected files

Tags: php, git, netbeans, github

Is it possible to use Git only with some files or directories instead of commiting the whole project?

I just created new project in PHP and want to share only one folder but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Add all the files and directories you want to ignore into the `.gitignore` file (if you don't already have one, create one)  line by line at the root directory of the git project

Comment: Also,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279533/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-to-only-include-certain-files-instead-of-ignoring-cer

Answer (score 0):

You can either *ignore* the stuff you don't want to commit, *exclude* them from commits or just don't add them.

**Ignore**

Use the `.gitignore`-file manually or select all files you don't want to commit and **`right click -> Git -> Ignore -> Ignore`**.

**Exlude**

Select the files (as above) and **`right click -> Git -> Ignore -> Exclude From Commit`** or exclude them in the commit dialog.

**See also**

- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files/987162)
- https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/
- http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore