# Including only .gitignore, .bashrc, .vimrc, .vim/ in a Git repo

Tags: git, gitignore

I thought I was pretty good with `.gitignore` files until just now.  I'm trying to include **only** the following files in a Git repo:

- .gitignore
- .bashrc
- .vimrc
- .vim/ (everything in this directory)

I have read several other answers on StackOverflow ([How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git), [Git ignore sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545602/git-ignore-sub-folders) and [Is there a way to tell git to only include certain files instead of ignoring certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279533/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-to-only-include-certain-files-instead-of-ignoring-cer/1279718#1279718)).  But, I can't seem to get my `.gitignore` file right.  Here's what I have in my `.gitignore` file presently:

```
*
.*
!.gitignore
!.bashrc*
!.vimrc
!.vim/
```

After I run `git init; git add .; git status` the repo contains:

```
$ git init; git add .; git status
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/username/.git/
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .bashrc
    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   .vimrc
```

I've tried variations on the last line of my `.gitignore` file, but to no avail.  Can anyone spot my mistake?

EDIT

I'm trying to find a solution which modifies **only** the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: No, my `.vim/` directory contains one sub-directory named `bundle`.  There a lot of files and directories under the `bundle` folder.  What do you mean by "the output seems correct"?  My goal is to include the `.vim/` folder and everything in it.

Comment: You can use `-force` flag :  `git add -f .vim`

Comment: I tried `!/.vim` with the same results.  I could use the `-force` flag, except I'm trying to find a solution that works by modifying only the `.gitignore` file.  I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ignore files only (`*` ignores files and folder)

```
**
.**
```

Then you can whitelist folders and their files:

```
!.vim/
!.vim/**
```

Double-check what `.gitignore` rule applies with:

```
git check-ignore -v .vim/afile
```

What you want is for `check-ignore` to return nothing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it didn't add the `.vim/` folder.  It only added `.gitignore`, `.bashrc` and `.vimrc`.  I first did `rm -rf ~/.git/`, then edited `.gitignore` using `**` and `.**`.  I then ran `git init; git add .; git status` to view the files added to the repo.

Comment: @MikeyE Try `git check-ignore -v .vim/afile` to see which ignore rule is applied. And I have edited the answer.

Comment: Your comments about `**` ignoring files and `*` ignore files and folders cleared it up for me.  I've selected your answer as the accepted answer.