# .gitignore ignoring files which are excluded from the ignore list

Tags: git, eclipse, gitignore

I'm doing a Java project using Eclipse with the in build git-functionality. I have an `Images` folder in the same directory as the `.gitignore` file.
I want to ignore all files in `Images` except `Destroyed-icon.png` `Layer_dot.png` `Not-enough-repair-packs-icon.png`.
According to [Is there a way to tell git to only include certain files instead of ignoring certain files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279533/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-to-only-include-certain-files-instead-of-ignoring-cer) I should be able to use the following in my `.gitignore` file, but is doesn't work. The whole `Images` directory is ignored.

```
Images
!Images/Destroyed-icon.png
!Images/Layer_dot.png
!Images/Not-enough-repair-packs-icon.png
```

I already tried adding/removing all `/` before and after `Images`, restarting eclipse, closing and reopening the project but none of that worked.
There is nothing to Pull as well, my local repository is up to date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: In the accepted answer of the above link, they make a note which might answer *exactly* why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Kraigolas yes, that's exactly what I needed, thx

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to deal with this is to ignore `Images`, and just `git add -f` the files you want to track. After they have been added, git will keep an eye on them regardless of what `.gitignore` says about them.

Comment: doesn't really answer my question but works fine, thx