# .gitignore syntax issue

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a given `extension` directory containing plenty of other directories. 
Among those plenty, one particular named `important` that I want to be staged by git. The others I don't. So I created a `.gitignore` file within my `extension` directory with the following content:

```
*
!README
!.gitignore
!important/**
```

My goal was saying to Git:

- ignore everything in this directory
- but keep the README file
- and also keep the .gitignore file
- and please, do keep also the `important` directory

But this is not working, only `README` and `.gitignore` are kept.
The syntax seems the right one to me so... I do not know where I am wrong.

Any suggestion is most welcomed.

Comment: A workaround I found was to issue `git add -f extension/important/*`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `**` to recursively got through a directory.

```
*
!README
!.gitignore
!important/
```

Take a look at this answer [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I am still facing the same issue. The `important` directory does not get staged.

Comment: ... I do not know what is wrong but I can't get it to work. Git does not stage the directory