# Which version control software allows to whitelist dirs?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, bazaar

I want to whitelist a couple of directories and a file:

```
/app
/config
/db
Gemfile
```

A go-to version control, `git`, does not allow to track a directory:

```perl
# .gitignore:
* # ignore all: suppose I prefer whitelisting
# but not the following things:
!/app/*
!/config/*
!/db/*
!Gemfile
```

Doesn't work: git only sees `Gemfile`.

Do you happen to know if any version control software allows to whitelist dirs and files?

**Edit 1**

Trying to apply https://stackoverflow.com/a/8025106/788700:

```sh
# Ignore everything:
*
# Don't ignore directories, so we can recurse into them:
!*/
# Don't ignore these dirs:
!app/*
!config/*
!db/*
# Don't ignore .gitignore and Gemfile:
!.gitignore
!Gemfile
```

— doesn't track dirs in `app/`, `config/` and `db/`.

**Edit 2: Solved**

Using [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024924/gitignore-ignore-all-files-then-recursively-allow-foo/8025106#comment15884195_8025106) from the above answer:

```sh
# Ignore everything:
*


# Don't ignore directories, so we can recurse into them:
!*/


# Don't ignore these dirs:
!app/*
!app/**/*

!config/*
!config/**/*

!db/*
!db/**/*


# Don't ignore .gitignore and Gemfile:
!.gitignore
!Gemfile
```

Seems to be working.

Comment: It's not clear, is this only a question about version control systems other than Git? (Your premise is incorrect; Git does allow you to do this, but you have to de-ignore the directory in which you _might_ have controlled files because Git doesn't descend into ignored directories even if you have subsequent patterns that might match files in those directories.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey: yeap if one de-ignores all the dirs, including all child dirs, it works, but from my point of view it is not usable (because a list of child dirs will be changing a lot). I'm just looking for any solution which will allow to whitelist dirs "recursively".

Comment: What is "whitelisting" in human terms?

Comment: Have you considered instead using a separate ignore file for each subdirectory? In [HG](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) you can use `subinclude:` for this.

Comment: @LazyBadger: by whitelisting I meant that some dirs are tracked recursively (including complete contents of these dirs). While all other files and dirs are ignored. So I can add `.passwords` file and be safe. This is opposed to traditional approach, where one would blacklist `.passwords` file to exclude it from tracking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15329081/960558 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8025106/960558 - detect differences with your code

Answer (score 2):

1. Git|Mercurial doesn't track empty directories, but if you'll add dummy-files in dirs - they will tracked (and successfully unignored)
2. Git|Mercurial will apply ignore-patterns only for new files (not tracked), thus - if you'll ignore all, but add some objects by hand, they will be tracked regardless of *ignore-file setting (but see above)
3. Subversion can track empty directories, but svn:ignore patterns are in common weaker, than equivalent mechanics in Git|Mercurial