# How to commit directory structure (directories with subdirectories) without files to git?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I'm trying to commit the following directory structure to git:

```
web
    /uploads
            /avatars
            /video
```

I put `.gitkeep` into `/web/uploads/avatars/` and `/web/uploads/video/` and added the following lines to `.gitignore` in the root of the repo:

```
/web/uploads/
!/web/uploads/avatars/.gitkeep
!/web/uploads/video/.gitkeep
```

But `git status` does not show any new files. Invoking `git add web/uploads/avatars/.gitkeep` outputs the following message:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
web/uploads/avatars/.gitkeep
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

How can I commit an empty directory structure into git repository?
P.S. git version is git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0

Comment: This is (because you want the lowest-level directory to be empty and the problem then simply floats up to each next level) a duplicate of [How do I add an empty directory to a git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452) (or, perhaps, of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/987142/1256452)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you exclude some directory, then everything under it will always be excluded, even if you put unignore something under it later. To unignore certain files or directories you have to unignore every parent directory of anything that you want to unignore. So your .gitconfig must be

```
!web/uploads/

web/uploads/*
!web/uploads/avatars/
!web/uploads/video/

web/uploads/avatars/*
web/uploads/video/*

!web/uploads/*/.gitkeep
```

But you should remember that .gitkeep is not a git feature, it just an agreement, simply it is a hidden file, so the name can be any

Answer (score 0):

Your `.gitignore` file ignored directory `/web/uploads` itself therefore its subdirectories and files will be ignored automatically regardless the following negated pattern.

If you want to add `/web/uploads/` but ignore files in it, the `.gitignore` can be like:

```
/web/uploads/*
# Next line tell git to add subdirectories back
!/web/uploads/**/
!/web/uploads/avatars/.gitkeep
!/web/uploads/video/.gitkeep
```

Or if you just want to add the directory, no matter there is file or no, then you don't need to touch `.gitignore`, just add the `.gitkeep` files, everything will work well.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore a directory, git doesn't check its subdirectories and files.

So, git doesn't check following lines.

```
!/web/uploads/avatars/.gitkeep
!/web/uploads/video/.gitkeep
```

If you want git to check subdirectories and files, use asterisk and ignore all files (not directory).

For example:

```
/web/uploads/*/*
```