# How do I ignore everything in my repo except a few files?

Tags: git

I've researched this and I can't seem to bump on a working solution.
I have a repo locally and want to ignore everything in it except two files, since those are the only ones necessary to build the program.

What I've tried is this:

Contents of .gitignore:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# not these files...
!.gitignore
!ApiTest/KLM_Service.cs
!ApiTest/Program.cs
```

The structure of my repo is this:

```
.git
ApiTest
  bin
  obj
  Properties
  App.config
  KLM_Service.cs
  Program.cs
.gitignore
```

I'm on Windows using GIT Bash.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded." - http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I can't test this since I'm on mobile now, but would reversing the everything rule with the file ignores work?

Comment: Nope, as the link says, there is no way to re-include a file where a parent directory of said file has been exluded.

Comment: I know this is a little old, but check out [this Stack Overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16318111/1386201) for a little more information about un ignoring a nested file. Again, not a best practice, but it is possible if you un-ignore all the way down the path, one folder at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your repo layout, I would strongly recommend against ignoring everything. While there are a lot of autogenerated files that you don't care about, the autogenerated filenames will never change. Your source code filenames will definitely change, though, which would force you to keep your `.gitignore` constantly up-to-date.

Since this is C# code, why don't you use a C#-specific .gitignore to start off, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/kmorcinek/2710267)?

Comment: I'm probably never gonna mess with this again, so that's the motivation. I'd like a simple layout on my remote, that's all basically.

Comment: @user3046061: and you'll get a simple layout, if you ignore the autogenerated stuff. Seriously, copy-paste the `.gitignore` I linked and you should be good to go -- no need to "whitelist" your source code files. (The former is also better practice, for when you want to make more complex programs).

Comment: That gitignore you linked seems more all encompassing than what I was using for C# so I'll use it around. Thanks.