# Ignore files with names starting with 'output'

Tags: git, substring, glob

I have a program that generates text files `output1.txt`, `output2.txt`, `output3.txt`, etc.. I want Git to ignore these files. I can't block text files, as I have some text files that shouldn't be ignored. Also, the files are dynamically generated (there is no limit to the number appearing after “output”), so can't add the file names statically. Can someone please help me with this?

PS. I've checked out this [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files), but it refers to a set of files alread known. In my case it might be a long list.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Pattern matching doesn’t just work before the extension. Just as much as you can ignore `*.txt`, you can ignore:

```
output*.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

if you want to ignore files with starting string, also you can do with extensions as well

for all extensions

> `startingFileName*.*`

2. files, extensions start with `mp` string like **mp3**,**mp4** etc

> `starting*.mp*`

Extra useful-case could be
Ignore files that ending with specified string

- `*.logs`
- `*.css.map`
- `*.etc.etc`

Answer (score 7):

Just add the following to your gitignore:

```
output*.txt
```

`*` is a "wildcard", so it will match anything.

Answer (score 3):

Using * just as in regex matching (or wildcard matching) will do the job. Just provide the entry

```
output*.txt
```

into your .gitignore file, and the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore all files that have same starting but different ending names, then you can use this patters (e.g. `output.txt`, `output.old.test.txt`, `output.save`, `output.anypattern`):

```
//.gitignore
output.*
```