# Git ignore all files but certain files in subdirectory

Tags: git

I have this dictionary hierarchy:

```
.
|-- Test
|   |-- file_c.z
|   `-- sub-dir
|       |-- file_d.t
|       `-- file_e.q
|-- file_a.x
|-- file_b.y
`-- .gitignore
```

Now how can I tell git ignore everything except `file_a.x` and `file_e.q`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Comment: @ChrisMaes: I've already read that question but it not resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Add following to your `.gitignore`

```
# Ignore everything
*
# Don't ignore .gitignore and your specific files files
!.gitignore
!file_a.x
!Test/sub-dir/file_e.q
```

Comment: It just make `file_a.x` get stayed, `Test/sub-dir/file_e.q` get ignored.

Comment: Updated the `.gitignore` content. What is the version of git you are using ?

Comment: I try your updated version but git still ignore file `file_e.q`. I'm using git version 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asterisk as wildcard.

```
Test/sub-dir/file_d.*
```

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude files from gitignore patterns with '!'

just write

```
Test/
!file_a.x
!file_e.q
```

in your .gitignore

Comment: This make git ignores everything except `.gitignore`, `file_a.x`, `file_b.y`

Comment: I thought this is what you wanted to do...?

Comment: No, I just want git ignore everything except `file_a.x` and `file_e.q`

Comment: have you previously added any of these files? if so, you need to remove everything first, commit these changes (incl the new .gitignore) and then add the files again. I guess this is the problem...

Comment: No, I've tested so many times, I create a new git repo and new `.gitignore` file. that just keep `file_a.x`, `file_b.y` and `.gitignore`