# How to commit a file that defies a pattern in .gitignore?

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, gitignore

I wan't to ignore every IPython Notebook found on my project so I put `*.ipynb` in .gitignore.

However, I would like to commit some specific *.ipynb files that will accompany a release (master branch). If possible, I would like git not to continue tracking those files after the commit, but I wouldn't mind if it does.

Comment: Once a file is tracked, it's tracked. If you add the file to Git it will continue to be tracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about this: [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

In summary, using the prefix ! in the gitignore file.