# Egit making Luna very slow, performance issues

Tags: java, eclipse, github, egit, eclipse-luna

When using the repositories from Egit within eclipse, navigation around the code and writing the code is very slow and crashes a lot as well as eclipse just not responding constantly.

It doesn't seem to be an issue with Luna as it did this when I had Kepler too, and my colleagues don't have this problem either.

Answer (score 8):

You can try those in any order:

- Shutdown Eclipse and in a console type: `git gc --aggressive`, restart Eclipse
- Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Label Decorations and unselect Git
- Preferences->Team->Git->Window Cache, [increase Window Cache to 300 m or more](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781578/)
- Preferences->Team->Git->Window Cache, use virtual memory mapping
- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

EGit will probably get faster over time as more people will report and fix it... see performance issues [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=performance).