# Git to ignore all files except certain files

Tags: git

I want git to keep track certain files only, so i wrote this gitignore file. In this file i tell git to ignore all the files except .ps1,.bat,.sql and .tab.I placed this gitignore file in root local working directory. 
Now the problem was, if the keep track files in subdirectory (BatchFile subdirectory), git will ignore them which i believed due to * . How to correct it ?

```
*
!*.ps1
!*.bat
!*.sql
!*.tab
```

My folder directory structure

```
Main
    BatchFile
    DB_Objects
              Table
              View
              and etc..
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand  what you mean ?

Comment: @user664481 he means that your question is a duplicate of another question i.e another one has asked this before check the questions and answers in the link provided

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want ignore patters to apply to all sub-directories but only to the directory `.gitignore` is in, prefix them with a slash, like `!/*.bat`.