# How to add proguard mapping file on git (exclude in gitignore, Android Studio)

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

I need to add this file on git (Android Studio Project)
***app/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/relese/mapping.txt***
This is my .gitignore file (root of the project)

```
...
build/
*/build/
!build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/release
...
```

This is my .gitignore file (module app)

```
...
/build
!/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/release
...
```

The files contained in app/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/release are always excluded by git.
Any suggetion on how I can solve it?
Regards

Comment: The mapping file is a build artifact, putting it under version control is a bad idea. Instead, store it along with the apk it corresponds to.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. After build the release apk, I will tag it...so the proguard file will match the exact version of the app. However, your comment did not answer to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
git add -f app/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/release/mapping.txt
```

You only need to use the -f flag the first time - .gitignore does not work for files that are already tracked.

However, I would recommend treating the mapping.txt file as a build artifact and NOT add it to version control, instead, store it along with your .apk file to wherever you are storing build artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to handle it in .gitignore file.

> If you want to ignore the whole content of a directory except one file inside it, you could write a pair of rules for each directory in the file path.

```
!/build
/build/*
!/build/outputs
/build/outputs/*
!/build/outputs
/build/outputs/mapping/*
!/build/outputs/mapping
/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/*
!/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor
/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/release/*
!/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/release
!/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/release/mapping.txt
```

PS: You have typo app/build/outputs/mapping/my_flavor/**relese**/mapping.txt

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16318111/4773117)