# Want to track a file / folder which was earlier ignored by .gitignore

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

I have a folder `public/lib` which was ignored by GIT as i added following to `.gitignore` file :

```
public/lib
```

I made initial committ & pushed changes into remote repository. Later realized i need to commit one folder in `public/lib` called `templates`. Then found this approach for **[Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)**

Changed my `.gitignore` file to :

```
public/lib
!public/lib/template/**/*
```

This is not helping me. I dont see `template` folder considered by GIT on next `git status`.

I am new to Git.

Comment: `git status --ignored` can list the ignored files. `git add -f -- ignored-files` can add ignored files by force.

Comment: This command basically adds all ignored files / files. How do i add particular folder by force ?

Comment: change `ignored_files` to particular files/folders.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, that solved the problem !! Big sigh of relief :)

Answer (score 1):

Your whitelist for the subdirectory looks a bit off to me.  Try this:

```
public/lib              # blacklist public/lib folder
!public/lib/template    # but exclude the template subfolder
```

Comment: After adding `!public/lib/template` in `.gitignore`, i expect `git status` to show `template` folder as untracked folder so that i can commit it next. Thats not happening @Tim. This is driving me nuts !!!!

Comment: You can't add empty folders in Git.  Please add a file to `public/lib/template` and then try `git status` again.

Comment: `template` folder already has `css` & `js` folder, which in turn have files inside them !! When i try `git status --ignore` its showing `public/lib` folder under `Ignore Files` section.

Comment: Yes. `git status` doesn't show `public/lib` but `git status --ignore` does in `Ignored Files` section.

Comment: But are the files under `public/lib/template` visible?  This was the whole point of your question.

Comment: no they are not visible even after following the pattern given by you in `.gitignore` file. I had to force add & then commit the `public/lib/template` folder.