# .gitignore * but a subfolder seems to be buggy

Tags: git

So I've read the principle but somehow I don't find a way of doing what I want

This is my `.gitignore`

```
*
!wp-content/*
```

And the wp-content folder is like this :

```
wp-content
  -- index.php
  -- languages/
  -- plugins/
  -- themes/
```

However it does not take in account the subfolder.
I've seen that I shoudl use `**` but it is not working either.

What is the proper way to include **every file / folder** under `wp-content`?

Comment: So you want to ignore everything *except* what's inside `wp-content`? Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files?rq=1

Comment: @J.Titus That's it, but I've read already every answer on stack and nothing seems to work properly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Remember to negate the ignore of `.gitignore` also, otherwise your rules won't work:

**.gitignore**

```
/*
!.gitignore
!wp-content
```

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/459750) helped me understand what was going on.

Comment: Daaaaamn ! You'r a Genius, Its the `/*`I was missing !