# Git add . failing on subdirectory that has a .git folder, even though being ignored

Tags: git, gitignore, conda, miniconda

We have a deep directory structure with multiple README files at different levels. For instance:

```
gitignoretest/
|-- 00README
|-- dir1
|   |-- 00README
|   |-- dir1
|   |   |-- 00README
|   |   |-- dir1
|   |   |-- dir2
|   |   |-- dir3
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file2
|   |-- dir2
|   |   |-- 00README
|   |   |-- dir1
|   |   |-- dir2
|   |   |-- dir3
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file2
|   |-- dir3
|   |   |-- 00README
|   |   |-- dir1
|   |   |-- dir2
|   |   |-- dir3
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file2
|   |-- file1
|   `-- file2
|-- dir3
|   |-- 00README
|   |-- dir1
|   |   |-- 00README
|   |   |-- dir1
|   |   |   |-- 00README
|   |   |   |-- dir1
|   |   |   |-- dir2
|   |   |   |-- dir3
|   |   |   |-- file1
|   |   |   `-- file2
|   |   |-- dir2
|   |   |   |-- 00README
|   |   |   |-- dir1
|   |   |   |-- dir2
|   |   |   |-- dir3
|   |   |   |-- file1
|   |   |   `-- file2

...
...
```

We want to ONLY version the `00README` files. We successfully tested this with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/188963) `.gitignore`

*.gitignore*

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!00README
# etc...

# ...even if they are in subdirectories
!*/
```

However, in the *real* scenario, one of the subdirectories is a `conda` installation which has some packages containing their own `.git` directories. When I do `git add .` it fails with the message:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: Applications/conda/lib/STAR-Fusion/STAR-Fusion.wiki/../.git/modules/STAR-Fusion.wiki
```

The real scenario is `../TopLevel/Applications/...` with `../TopLevel/.gitignore`. Here are the things I've tried:

*../TopLevel/.gitignore*

```
# Ignore everything
*
/Applications/conda/**/*
/Applications/miniconda3/**/*
/Applications/newconda/**/*

Applications/conda/**/*
Applications/miniconda3/**/*
Applications/newconda/**/*

/**/.git
**/.git

/**/.git/**
**/.git/**

# But not these files...
!.gitignore
!00README.md
!USE_APPS
# etc...

# ...even if they are in subdirectories
!*/
```

But not hitting the mark.

---

**EDIT**
To address the issue of "untracking" subdirectories with `.git` folders as mentioned by @VonC, I present a completely fresh creation of the git repository. Note: the repository being added as the remote is a freshly minted `--bare` repository.

```
balter@server:/home/.../TopLevel$ rmdir .git
balter@server:/home/.../TopLevel$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/.../TopLevel/.git/
balter@server:/home/.../TopLevel$ git remote add origin git@server.ohsu.edu:path/repo.git
balter@server:/home/.../TopLevel$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
#   00README.md
#   Applications/
#   InstallationPackages/
#   USE_APPS
#   gitignoretest/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
balter@server:/home/.../TopLevel$ git add .
fatal: Not a git repository: Applications/conda/lib/STAR-Fusion/STAR-Fusion.wiki/../.git/modules/STAR-Fusion.wiki
```

Comment: did you try `git add --all` instead of `git add .` ? the latter is only for the first commit, right ?

Comment: Well, that was the first commit :)  But I just tried `git add --all` and got the same error :(

Comment: I see... Did you tried to remove all configured git with `rm -fr .git` and `git init` again then `git add .`?

Comment: Yes, but I'll try it again...

Comment: Nope. Did `rmdir .git; git init; git remote add origin git@......git; git add .` and got same error :(

Comment: ok I'm out of idea... I think the best thing to do is to manually remove the git in conda folder... No git, no error.

Comment: I'm guessing it would come back every time we `conda update` and there may be many packages that have that :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider the all tree structure as one repository, you need to remove the nested `.git` subfolders first: see "[Initial push to GitHub Missing Sub Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42655126/6309)".

Regarding The ignore rules, if you want to ignore everything but the OOREMEADE files, you need fisrt to exclude the folders

```
*
!**/
```

Then you can exclude files:

```
!00README
```

Make sure those files are untracked first (`git status`)

> Our Applications directory has a conda installation that seems to install many packages by cloning git repositories. If I go and delete all the .git directories then whenever I run conda update, either it will fail because it no longer has the repos it needs, or it will re-clone them.

First, you don't ignore `.git` folders: their parent folder represents a nested git repo. That is the folder (the parent of the `.git` folder) you want to ignore, that way a `git add .` won't record a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in index of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

Second, "`Not a git repository: .../../.git/modules/...`" means the conda nested repo has **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, whose [support is still in progress with conda](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/pull/1492): that conda installation folder would need a `git submodule update --init --recursive` in order to initialize the proper nested submodules.

Comment: Trying it. A couple of questions: 1) it "worked" in our test directory, albeit there were no folders that were themselves repositories. 2) if I understand,  `!**/` is to ignore anything that is actually a folder, and not a file. Right?

Comment: @abalter 2) yes: if a folder is ignored, any rule involving an element in that ignored subfolder won't be used at all. 1) What is the question ;)

Comment: Tried the above, and still got fatal error :(  Regarding 1) the question was that in the test directory (tree shown in original question) the `.gitignore` I showed worked fine in terms of ignoring directories. So why is it failing when there is a `.git` directory somewhere down the road? Maybe I need to ignore all directories starting with "."?

Comment: That is what my first link k details

Comment: see my edit. Does that fully address the issue of needing to make sure the files are un-tracked?

Comment: @abalter your edit seems to indicate you still have nested git repo inside your freshly new git repo: remove any .git subfolder (beside the one created by git init)

Comment: @VonC--oh golly I must not have been clear at all with my original question. Our Applications directory has a conda installation that seems to install many packages by cloning git repositories. If I go and delete all the `.git` directories then whenever I run `conda update`, either it will fail because it no longer has the repos it needs, or it will re-clone them. So there is no way to fix the problem by removing those directories. We need a solution that works with them there.

Comment: @abalter OK. I have added some information and edited the answer.