# Initial push to GitHub Missing Sub Directory

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I made an initial push to GitHub from our codebase but one of the two websites sub directory didn't get pushed for some reason.

We had `.git` files in both sub directories but removed them prior to making this new combined repository.

We've tried adding a single file to the sub directory but SourceTree isn't seeing picking up the changes.

How would you add those subfolders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We had .git files in both sub directories but removed them prior to making this new combined repository.

It is not enough: you need to remove (untrack) the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (folder name of the two subdirectories, viewed as a [special entry in the index of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))

```
 git rm --cached subfolder1
 git rm --cached subfolder2

 git commit -m "remove gitlinks"
```

Then you can add and commit (provided the nested .git/ folders are indeed gone)

```
git add .
git commit -m "add two subfolders"
git push
```