# Visual Studio doesn't seem to respect "!" in .gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm trying to check-in a dll to my source control. This is an unfortunate thing i have to do because of a decision I'm not in control of or agree with. All other dll's are managed by Nuget and so for my automatic build I don't need to include them in my source control.

My issue is that I need it to be in the bin folder within the project so after it builds it works. I have made an exception in the .gitignore_global for this specific dll and am trying to make an exception at the end of my .gitignore of the form.

![Bb]in/Logging.dll

If I comment out or remove the

[Bb]in/

line the file gets included (and a few more that I don't want to include). I can't seem to get the .gitignore to make an exception for just one file with the '!' symbol which .. from my understanding is supposed to make exceptions to ignore rules.

Here is my .gitignore

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates
# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
[Xx]64/
[Xx]86/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]in/
bld/
[Oo]bj/

# Visual Studio 2015 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

# DNX
project.lock.json
artifacts/

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opendb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile
*.VC.db

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
*.sap

# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

# JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
.JustCode

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml
nCrunchTemp_*

# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

appraisal-analytics/Download/*
appraisal-analytics/Users/*

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml

# TODO: Un-comment the next line if you do not want to checkin
# your web deploy settings because they may include unencrypted
# passwords
#*.pubxml
*.publishproj

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config
# NuGet v3's project.json files produces more ignoreable files
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets

# Microsoft Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef

# Microsoft Azure Emulator
ecf/
rcf/

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/
BundleArtifacts/

# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!*.[Cc]ache/

# Others
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/
orleans.codegen.cs

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf

# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/

# GhostDoc plugin setting file
*.GhostDoc.xml

# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat

# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg

# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt

# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions

# LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
ModelManifest.xml

# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe

# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/.github
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/dist/js/i18n
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/docs/dist/js/i18n
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/docs/options.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/docs/methods.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/docs/index.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/docs/examples.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/mkdocs.yml
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/js/i18n
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/js/.jshintrc
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/less
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/nuget
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/sass
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/LICENSE
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/CHANGELOG.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/bower.json
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/.bower.json
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/docs
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-select/docs/custom_theme
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/docs
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/grunt
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/less
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/js/.jshintrc
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/js/.jscsrc
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/tests
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/README.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/package.json
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/LICENSE
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/Gruntfile.js
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/CONTRIBUTING.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/composer.json
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/CHANGELOG.md
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/bower.json
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/.travis.yml
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/.npmignore
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/.gitignore
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/.editorconfig
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/.bower.json
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/Chart-js/docs
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/Chart-js/.github
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/Chart-js/samples
/appraisal-analytics/wwwroot/lib/Chart-js/scripts/release.sh

#include these files
!Logging.dll
![Bb]in/Logging.dll
```

.gitignore_global

```
#ignore thumbnails created by windows
Thumbs.db
#Ignore files build by Visual Studio
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.dll
!Logging.dll
!*/Logging.dll
![Bb]in/Logging.dll
```

Comment: See in particular [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29932318/1256452) (and subsequent ones) to the duplicate. The problem here is that you tell Git "ignore Bin" so it does, so it never even *finds* `Bin/Logging.dll` in the first place and cannot un-ignore it. Do not ignore `Bin` itself, simply ignore things *inside* `Bin` so that as Git is enumerating all those things, it encounters `Bin/Logging.dll`.

Comment: Question, my understanding is that it should ignore all files if I do [Bb]in/* but it doesn't ignore any files at all with [Bb]in/* like that solution says. So while I'm sure this is correct for git it doesn't work from within visual studio. That was actually my very first solution attempt ... but that doesn't work.

Edit: I just ignored all the individual files there except TitanLogging.dll, it is not a 'correct' solution but it works.

Comment: Using `[Bb]in/*` *should* work. Make sure there is no hidden white-space after the `*`, though. This often trips people up, since the white-space is not visible, but some (not all) versions of Git count it. (Git versions before v2.0.0 do not ignore trailing white space in `.gitignore`.)