# How to get a count of the total number of lines in almost all files in git repository?

Tags: git

I have a problem where I have files in a directory with extensions .doc, .js, .pdf, .md, .txt

I want to ignore all files except .txt and get a count of the total number of lines in those files.

Using this command, I can ignore ones with .md, but how do I include other extensions?

```
git ls-files *[^.md] | xargs cat | wc -l
```

I tried:

```
git ls-files *[^.md|^.pdf||^.doc] | xargs cat | wc -l
```

but that does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Comment: I want to get a count of lines in a file. .gitignore has nothing to do with this. I need to be able to execute this on command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `git ls-files` to do the work of limiting the files for you, you can just insert a `grep` into your pipeline for that.  This variant is affirmative, selecting only the extensions you list:

```
git ls-files | egrep '\.(doc|js|pdf|md)$' | xargs cat | wc -l
```

This variant is negative, excluding `.txt` and keeping anything else:

```
git ls-files | egrep -v '\.txt$' | xargs cat | wc -l
```

Note, however, that `wc -l` doesn't really give any meaningful output for binary files like Word docs and PDFs.

Comment: Is it possible to also exclude specific directories?

Comment: sure, just throw a `| egrep -v '/name-of-directory/'` into the pipeline.

Comment: You sir are a genius.