# Git not fetching ignored tracked files

Tags: git, mingw, gitignore

This question is almost the opposite of the FAQ of how to stop Git from tracking ignored files. In this case, **I want to track them, and not ignore them.**

I have a `.gitignore` file which has the line:

`**/*.exe`

Most of the time, `.exe` files are products of builds, and are to be ignored (This project is hosted on a combination of MinGW & Cygwin, so the binaries run on Windows.)

However, there are exceptions to this ignore rule. I have added a few `.exe` files to my source tree. As I understand it, `.gitignore` does not apply to tracked files (files in the index).

However, when I clone my respository, the `.exe` files are not fetched.

If I do a `git status` on the file *in the original repository where I added it*, I get:

`$ git status program.exe
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

The file also exists in the working tree:

`$ ls -l program.exe
-rwxrwx---+ 1 abc xyz 23040 Mar 20 15:35 program.exe`

`$ git log program.exe`

`commit 412fd58b5a11bf6a40f661109e71f2c0026c1643
Author: abc <abc@xyz.com>
Date:   Sat Apr 1 02:21:40 2017 -0700`

`cleanup`

`commit b0a2efd4dc17b70d046c1e7d78e3142cf29410ba
Author: abc <abc@xyz.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 20 18:41:00 2017 -0700`

`Initial version`

I have pushed the commits to a bare repository on another server. I can find the blob corresponding to the latest checkin in the bare repository:

`MyProject.git/objects/41/2fd58b5a11bf6a40f661109e71f2c0026c1643`

So obviously it is being tracked. But when I clone the repository, it does not appear in the working tree. *On a cloned repository*:

`$ git status program.exe
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

`$ ls -l program.exe
ls: cannot access 'program.exe': No such file or directory`

I am not using `assume-unchanged` or the like.

1. Are ignored but tracked files still ignored when fetched in other repositories?
2. How do you force them to be fetched even though they match `.gitignore`?
3. Do you need to exclude them from matching `.gitignore` in order to be fetched?

`$ git --version
git version 2.12.0.windows.1`

**Edit: Remember, I'm not trying to ignore tracked files after adding them to `.gitignore`; I'm trying to *fetch* tracked and committed files, despite them matching `.gitignore`.**

Comment: What does `git add program.exe` tell you ?

Comment: `git show --name-status 412fd58b` : wasn't prorgram.exe removed from tracking in the last commit you mention ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: I think there's a key insight here about what *tracked* means

Between my original answer and a lot of discussion below, I realized something that I think is non-obvious.  It certainly was not obvious to me when I first used Git (probably for months if not years).  There are two parts here:

- In Git, *tracked* means *in the index*.
- But, the index (the next commit you will make) *changes* every time you check out some specific commit, including `git checkout otherbranch`, for instance.

This means that *whether a file is tracked* is a relative thing, not an absolute.  File *F* may be tracked after `git checkout branch1` and then untracked after `git checkout branch2`.  It may have been tracked in a past commit on branch `master`, and untracked now on branch `master`.  If the file is both untracked *and* ignored, but *was* tracked in the past and *is* currently in the work-tree, it can be quite difficult to figure out what's going on.  The file will not appear in a new clone, even though it's in the history.

(Original, complete answer below the line here.)

---

> However, when I clone my respository, the `.exe` files are not fetched.

A `git clone` operation does not fetch *any* files.  Instead, it fetches *commits.*  Now, it's true that commits contain files, so this might seem like a pointless bit of pedantic quibbling, but it's central to your problem, and in fact to almost all of Git, so it really matters.  Git doesn't care about *files;* Git is all about commits.

The commits themselves form the history.  Each commit contains some set of files, but also has a back-pointer to a previous commit: "This is what we have now.  This is the hash ID of the commit we had before."  We call this the *parent* of the commit.  That parent commit also has a parent of its own.  This backwards-looking chain *is* the history in the repository.

A branch name like `master` is Git's way of recording the *current* hash ID for that branch.  Git starts here, at the most recent commit, using the branch name; and then Git works backwards if needed, obtaining older (parent) commits and going to still-older (grandparent, great-grandparent, etc) commits as requested.

Running `git clone` copies the branch name, and its commit, and that commit's parent, and the parent's parent, and so on; and that way you get all the history.  Each commit carries with it the files that were stored with that commit, so once you have all the commits, you have not only all the *current* files, but also all the *previously current* parent-commit files, and every earlier file all the way back to the very first commit.  But all these files are hidden away in a secret, Git-only format that is no good to anything but Git.  Still, that's what `git clone` copies.

Of course, to to make Git actually do anything useful, we need the files in some actually-useful form.  So Git adds something to this commit history stuff—but it's not something that gets *cloned;* and that's where your problem comes in.

#### What's in a repository

In a useful (i.e., non-`--bare`) repository, we need not only all the *commits* and various branch names to remember their most-recent hash IDs, we also need a *work-tree*.  The work-tree is where we can work with actual files.  These are arranged in a tree structure, with top level files and directories, and more files and sub-directories in the directories, as needed.  (Hence the name "work tree": it's a tree of working-form files.)

Git also throws in another thing Git calls the *index*.  The short description of the index is that it's where you build the *next* commit.  If you never make any changes to your own repository, this index just kind of gets in your way, but Git still forces you to know about it.  If you *do* make changes, the index is crucial, because the *way* to make changes is to modify things in the work-tree, then use `git add` to copy those modifications back into the index, so that they are *staged* for that next commit.  When you then run `git commit` to make a *new* commit, Git copies whatever is in the index *now*—i.e., all the old stuff that was there before, except for whatever you replaced by `git add`ing new stuff—into the new commit.

This really is very important to know: **the index tracks what's in the work-tree.**  In fact, that's exactly what "tracked" means: *tracked* means *in the index.*  But the index is also *what will be in the next commit*, and it therefore starts out matching *what was in the current commit*.

You can—and usually *do*—have, in the work-tree, files that are deliberately *not* tracked.  For instance, your `*.exe` files are untracked, on purpose.  Being untracked means they are not in the index.  That means they are not in the *current commit* either,<sup>1</sup> and now we can see that there is going to be a problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>That is, they are not in the current commit *unless* the index is "dirty" and thus needs to be written out to a new commit.  Again, this is how you make new commits in the first place: you modify stuff in the work-tree—such as modifying files, or adding all-new files, or removing existing files—and then you copy those "dirty" work-tree files into the index, "dirtying" the index.  Then you `git commit` to make a *new* commit.  The new commit's parent is what was the current commit, and its files are whatever was in the index.  Git then writes the new commit's hash ID into the branch name, and the new commit is now part of the history, to be saved forever.

---

#### Objection: "I can find the blob"

You mentioned that:

> I can find the blob corresponding to the latest checkin in the bare repository: `MyProject.git/objects/41/2fd58b5a11bf6a40f661109e71f2c0026c1643`

That means the file was committed *at some point*.  It's in some *historical* commit.  That does not mean that the file is in the *most recent* commit on a branch like `master`.  The repository has, in Git-only internal (compressed object) format, *every* version of *every* file ever committed.  And, you can, and often do, have, in your work-tree, a file that is not in the index and not in the current commit.  That file might well match a file that you did commit in the past.

Hence, the presence of the file in the *repository* does not mean it's in the latest *commit* on some particular branch.  It does mean you can extract the historical file.  For instance, given the above, you can:

```
git show 412fd58b5a11bf6a40f661109e71f2c0026c1643 > foo.exe
```

to extract it to `foo.exe` at any time.  If you know the commit hash and path, you can use that as well:

```
git show 1234567:path/to/foo.exe > foo.exe
```

and if the commit has a *name* (such as a branch or tag name):

```
git show name:path/to/foo.exe > foo.exe
```

You *can* use this method to extract historical files, but it's obviously somewhat painful.

#### What `git clone` does after it fetches all the commits

As we noted above, `git clone` first copies commits and branch names.  In fact, by default, it *renames* these branch-names to what Git calls "remote-tracking branches".  But then, as its last step before it quits and calls everything good and ready-to-go, `git clone` *fills in your work-tree*.

The *way* it fills in your work-tree is to `git checkout` some branch name, usually `master`.  This branch name remembers the hash ID of the latest commit for that branch.  That commit was made from an index, and that index *did not have `.exe` files in it.*  So the most recent `master` commit *does not have `.exe` files in it.*

Since this work-tree is all new, and the commit being checked out has no `.exe` files in it, your new work-tree has no `.exe` files in it.  That is why they are missing.

If those `.exe` files *do* exist in some *other* commit in the repository, then they are there in the repository, and you can get them out.  You just don't get them out with a simple:

```
git checkout master
```

because that *only* extracts, into the index and then on into the work-tree, the files that were saved for the latest commit on `master`.

#### So where *do* you get your `.exe` files?

Well, that part is up to you.  Git gives you no pre-packaged solution here.  They may be in the work-tree of the other Git repository you are cloning, but there is nothing in the clone protocol to take the *work-tree* of the other Git.

One way to deal with this would be to have a commit that contains nothing *but* the latest `.exe` files.  You could then tell Git:

  Extract into my work-tree, without extracting into the index, all the files from the commit whose hash ID is
  `feede3e`

for instance, assuming of course that that commit has that hash ID.  This turns out to be surprisingly difficult, since Git *really* wants to extract files from commits into the index before copying them to the work-tree.  Putting them into the index makes them *tracked*, which is not what you want here.  Of course, getting those `.exe` files into a commit in the first place requires—well, what else: wait for it ... have you guessed it yet?  Yes, this requires putting those `.exe` files into the index!

Git just won't let you have it both ways.  Either the files are tracked, so they are in the index, so they *do* go into commits; or they are untracked, so they are not in the index, so they do *not* go into commits.  Pick one and stick with it.  If you like, use `git worktree add`, or a separate clone of this repository, or a completely separate repository, to create a second repository or work-tree that uses a *different* branch that *does* have the `.exe` files tracked and committed.  In fact, you might well want this branch or other repository to track and save *only* `.exe` files.  Then you can simply copy the `.exe` files over from there.

Or, of course, you can obtain them from some place that does have them, but by some method other than `git clone`.

(It *is* actually possible to do all this without a separate work-tree, using various of Git's *plumbing* commands and a temporary index, but it's fairly tricky and not how Git was built to work.  In any case, note that you will want a name—such as a branch name—that you can remember easily that gets you the *latest* commit with the *latest* `.exe` files.  The idea of having a branch name that remembers hash IDs for you, with the commit object saving the files, and also remembering the previous commit object ... well, that's a *branch*.  That's what Git *does:* it keeps branch names that remember commit hashes that remember files that were saved out of the index.  So you really *do* want a separate work-tree and separate index where you update and commit the files.  You don't really *want* to work outside the Git model after all.)

#### The `.gitignore` file is a red herring

What an entry in `.gitignore` does is two main things:

- It *suppresses complaints* about untracked files.  If `foo.exe` exists in the work-tree but is not in the index and hence will not be saved in the next `git commit`, Git *whines* at you.  It keeps telling you, over and over again, "Hey, `foo.exe` is not going to be committed!  Remember to add `foo.exe` to the index!  Don't forget `foo.exe`, or it won't get committed!"  This gets obnoxious, and gets in the way of the complaints you *want* to see, about files you really *did* forget.  So adding `foo.exe` or `*.exe` to `.gitignore` shuts up this complaint.
- It suppresses `foo.exe` from being *automatically* added by `git add -a` or similar.  Rather than manually `git add`ing one file at a time to your index, you can add dirty work-tree files en masse by mentioning a directory name, or using `--all`, or using shell globs like `git add *`.  If `foo.exe` is currently untracked *and* is listed in `.gitignore`, these won't actually copy `foo.exe` into the index.  Even `git add *` will skip it, with a complaint; `git add .` or `git add -a` will skip it with no complaint.

Note that listing a file name in `.gitignore` has no effect if the file *is* tracked.  Entries in `.gitignore` are mostly about preventing the file from *becoming* tracked, not stopping anything that is already in effect.

Comment: @leek: no, they are *not* tracked (in the current index); if they were, they would have been extracted. See the "objection" section I added.  The adjective *tracked* applies relative to the index; it's not a repository-wide absolute.

Comment: The .exe files were added before ANY .gitignore files were added. They should be part of all previous checkins.

Comment: They must have been removed from the index, with `git rm --cached`, and then committed.  Otherwise they would be in the commit, and would wind up in the index, and have been extracted to the new clone's work-tree. Note that you can use `git ls-tree -r <branchname>` to view what's in the tree at the tip commit of the given branch name.

Comment: How can I do a "git status" on an .exe, and it says it's up-to-date if it's not tracked?

Comment: `git status` doesn't look at just one file: it runs two `git diff`s (with `--name-status`), one from `HEAD` to index, and one from index to work-tree. If file *F* is not in the index, and not in the `HEAD` commit, the first `git diff` never mentions it.  If *F* is not in the index and is in the work-tree, the second `git diff` *would* mention it as untracked, except that `.gitignore` says "don't whine about this please!"

Comment: Okay, how I do I add them back to the index, without adding all the other *.exe worth ignoring? If they're not in the index, how are they still "tracked" and "up to date"?

Comment: I know Git is commit-based instead of file-based; no need to reiterate that point. But still, a file has a certain status in a commit/revision.

Comment: I know that git status only goes on hashes of actual file content, and git diff can consider whitespace and other filters; that's a separate topic.

Comment: Suppose that `git add foo.exe` says "I am skipping foo.exe as it is marked ignored".  Then `git add --force foo.exe` will add it anyway. It will be tracked from that point onward until it is again removed from the index. It's a bit dangerous (in one sense) to have a file tracked yet apparently-ignored, because if you ever *remove* it from the index (with `git rm --cached`), Git won't mention anything about this, and you'll find the file mysteriously vanishing from the work-tree in the future, and have to go extract it from an old commit. But it will work.

Comment: Note, also, that if you `git checkout otherbranch` and the tip commit of `otherbranch` lacks file `foo.exe`, it will be removed from index and work-tree. Once you `git checkout master` again it will come back (since it's in that branch's tip commit), but I find this behavior extremely annoying (I have done it to myself several times, not with `.exe` files but with config files). If the file is marked for ignore, you can find yourself losing changes you made-and-did-not-commit, as well. (I recently renamed a config file to work around this.)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations. I'll digest them to understand the whole situation.

Comment: (On your update comment:) That's an interesting way of looking at it. I didn't know it could get so twisted. I understand separate branches, worktrees, and stages, but the nature of the index is more complicated than I thought. I thought it just meant "tracking", as you say.

Comment: @leek: yeah, there's a reason Mercurial doesn't expose the dirstate (its rough equivalent of Git's index). :-)

Comment: As for the comment 5 parents ago, which says "Suppose that git add foo.exe says "I am skipping foo.exe as it is marked ignored", if you used an explicit command like "git add", then no exclusion should apply.

Comment: Perhaps it should (add, with a warning, "adding a file that I'd ignore if you hadn't listed it specifically"). Perhaps if you coded this up with a config file switch, the Git folks would take it. They're not keen on behavior changes without such a config switch though.

Answer (score 0):

your build files are on bin folder . so you must add to your .gitignore just :

```
bin/*.exe or bin/*
```

and you should remove this line from your gitignore file :

```
**/*.exe
```

edit: if you want to ignore all exe files except some of them , you can exclude them using "!" at the begin of the line pattern , have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/5410373

Comment: No, the build files are scattered all around in disorganized fashion. I can't control this organization of files, since it's third-party software, although I have a copy of it. But there are tools with .exe extension similarly scattered, which are tracked files and which should not be ignored.

Comment: That may be a workaround, but the real question is: Does Git avoid fetching files matching .gitignore, even if they are tracked? That would seem to be a bug.

Comment: in this case, to confirm the issue : delete the git cahe and check again the tracked files : 
>>>git rm -r --cached 
>>>git add .
>>>git commit

Comment: On which repository? The one which has the files in the working tree, or the clone which is missing them? There's nothing to "commit". I don't want to risk losing any files.

Comment: remove cache from the wrong tree , this may happen when you update .gitignore but files have been tracked already, removing cahe won't change your files . you can also use >>>git rm --cached <file> to remove a specific tracked file from cache

Comment: A straight "git clone" from scratch reproduces the missing tracked files. Remember, I'm not trying to ignore tracked files after adding them to .gitignore; I'm trying to fetch tracked and committed files, despite them matching .gitignore.