# Committing changes to /platforms/android/project.properties

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

To fix a recently problem with "[com.google.android.gms.license](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/firebase-android-build-error-with-error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms-license/125329)" the recommended solution is to edit `platforms/android/project.properties` to specific the version of the libraries

old:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+
```

new:

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11+
```

However the Ionic scaffolder deliberately out `platforms/` into the .gitignore file so these changes will not be committed and shared to other dev. How/where should I make this change so that it persists?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files

Comment: @Duannx Since Ionic put those items into git-ignore on purpose I don't think I should be modifying it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release) plugin to align the versions specified by various plugins during the Cordova build process so you don't need to modify/exclude `platforms/android/project.properties`:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release  --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=11+
```