# Is it possible to control the version of a git repository state?

Tags: git

I am working on an interactive git tutorial that a user learns how to use git by following a series of instructions and operating a real git repository.
To prevent the learner from ruining the repository or taking wrong steps (and causing the tutorial cannot be continued), I am thinking of taking snapshots of the state of the repository (refs, index, and HEAD etc.) betweeen every few steps and reset to the last one when something unexpected happens.

As *taking snapshots* of a repo sounds like doing some sort of version control for the `.git` folder to me, I am wondering if it is possible to use any version control tool to do the work?

I have tried to put a git repo inside another git repo, and [set the .gitignore of the parent repo to include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files) .git folder of the child, but there is no luck. `git status` does not show `.git` as untracked directory.

Would be glad to hear any idea that can help me taking snapshots of the `.git` folder or tricks to preserve status of a git repo and apply it back later.

### edit 1

Tried `git add -f` to force add the `.git` folder, but git refused to add it and threw an error message.

Fortunately, another really dumb trick works. Renaming `.git` to any other name would be good enough to trick git to treat it as a normal folder. It is an acceptable solution to me, but not perfect, though.

That being said, since @ErikMD mentioned that my attempts to preserver git repository state via copying `.git` does not seem feasible at first sight, I am wondering if I have overlooked something critical? Would there be any problem to keep snapshots of a git repository by managing `.git` with a version control toll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "workaround" does not seem feasible at first sight (If you try to commit a `.git` subfolder contained in a parent git repo, you will get some kind of (broken) git-submodule...)

*To be more precise:* Git is not designed to track the low-level contents of `.git` folders as regular files. Instead, Git allows to combine several repositories (several subfolders containing themselves a `.git` subfolder) in a root repository. This corresponds to the so-called [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) feature. But setting up a submodule correctly requires using dedicated commands, which in turn also updates a special file `.gitmodules`. Hence what I had said earlier that you might obtain a "broken git-submodule layout" if you don't follow the normal workflow. Actually, the use of git-submodules is rather heavy and cumbersome in practice, compared to more recent features such as [git subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree).

However I think you could achieve what you want (facilitate the recovery of the repo for an automatic tutorial system) by relying on [git reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) or related commands to restore=overwrite the history, index, and working directory (the 3 mains parts of a repository) as well as branches and tags…

To exemplify my suggestion, assuming we only deal with one branch:

1. The "state" of the current active branch (`HEAD`) can be identified by the corresponding SHA1:

   ```
   $ git rev-parse --verify HEAD
   0ed45a5994bceea7c6b1d6530c72cd9ce29a46af  # for example
   ```
2. Suppose the user did a wrong step:

   ```
   $ git add UnwantedFile && git commit -m "Unwanted commit"
     # or
   $ git reset --hard HEAD~3  # remove 3 commits by mistake
   ```

   (and you notice it using appropriate commands)
3. Then you can restore the state of the working dir. + index + current branch by doing:

   ```
   $ git reset --hard 0ed45a5994bceea7c6b1d6530c72cd9ce29a46af
   ```

   (or if ever the step 1 had not been performed at first to remember the previous state, the reflog could give the required hint):

   ```
   $ git reflog
   d62277c84 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~3
   0ed45a599 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to V8.8.2
   …
   $ git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
   ```

To conclude, I only see three ways to achieve what you want:

1. Use manual `rsync` or `bash` hacks to overwrite the repo if you want to rollback it, but this is maybe not very satisfactory;
2. Use standard commands such as `git reset`, `git branch`, `git checkout` or `git tag`… (depending on the focus of the tutorial you are working on) to reset the repo accordingly;
3. Or use a local remote (or a local clone, in one way or the other) with appropriate commands such as `git push --mirror` or `git pull`/`git fetch`?

Comment: Thanks for your idea. This approach is similar to what I thought in the first place. Tracking key information such as current branch location and use it to reset when necessary, simple and clean. However, I plan to teach branch merging in the tutorial so there would be plenty branches in the repository. Keeping all of them tracked would be quite tedious. Therefore I am seeking a way to take complete snapshots of a repo to simplify the backup/restore process.

Comment: I am curious about your description "you will get some kind of (broken) git-submodule", which refers to the result of a full copy of a .git folder. What do you mean by "broken"? I thought the copy will be exactly the status of the repo. What am I missing?

Comment: @YAC I've added one paragraph to explain git-submodules in more depth, then a few suggestions at the end of my answer.