# Git stash is undeleting a deleted file and adding it to untracked files

Tags: git

On commit I am rebuilding my application for a node project and the built files are placed in the `dist` directory. To avoid problems with files in the `dist` directory already being staged, I do the following:

- Unstage the dist directory
- Reverse any changes in the dist directory
- Stash any unstaged or untracked files
- Build the application
- Stage the `dist` directory
- Unstash the unstaged and untracked files

These are the commands I use:

```
git reset HEAD -- dist && \
git checkout -- dist && \
git stash push -k -u -m "build" && \
npm run build && \
git add . && \
git stash pop
```

This worked fine until today. I am getting some odd behavior with a deleted file that is undeleted and untracked after the above commands are run.

Before running the above commands the `git status` output looks like this:

```
On branch master                                        
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.    
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)        

Changes to be committed:                                
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)           

        deleted:    scripts/substenv.js
```

After running the commands the `git status` output looks like this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    scripts/substenv.js

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        scripts/substenv.js
```

The untracked file appears after the `git stash push -k -u -m "build"` command.

Can anyone please explain why/what is happening?

Comment: If you have verified that `git status` before `git stash push -k -u` says that `scripts/substenv.js` is to be deleted (i.e., is not in the index despite being in the `HEAD` commit) and that immediately after `git stash push -k -u`, `scripts/substenv.js` exists in the work-tree, then you have found a bug in `git stash`. However, if it's *not* in the work-tree after that point, but appears later, that's probably all normal. To prove it's a bug in `git stash`, reduce the example further, to get a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the file to the `.gitignore` to stop seeing it in the `Untracked files` list.

Basically your stash has the file in it, then it adds it back when you re-apply the stash.

On a side note, I'm kinda confused by your setup/commands, why don't you just add the `dist` folder to the `.gitignore` file?

**Update based on comments:**

I think you might need to update your `npm build` script. Since you need to publish your `dist` folder, the files in it should be checked in. Use the `build` folder as an intermediate step, and add it to `.gitignore`.

- Build the app with `npm build`
- This will create bunch of files in `build/` folder (which should be ignored)
- Copy the files you want/need to check-in into your `dist` folder
- Profit

Comment: Hi, thx for the quick response. If I understand what you are suggesting, this means I would also have to add any future file I delete to the .gitignore file. Correct? For a one off this is acceptable, but I would prefer a solution that wouldn't require me to manually intervene.

Comment: To answer your question: the dist folder is required for publication to a private npm registry.

Comment: Well this all depends on your build script, if you just want the same files to be committed like `myapp.min.js` (output of your build script), then you can ignore all the **other files** in the dist folder. Check this link to see how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files