# No untracked files after git ignoring everything except

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git folder with .gitignore structured like this:

```
input/
src/
output/
additional-1/
additional-2/
file.csv
file.txt
```

And my `.gitignore` currently looks like this:

```
input/
output/
file.txt
```

There are some files already (particularly from `src/`) added to git, and there are plenty which are not. I have noticed that it would probably be a lot easier for me to ignore all files except some directories/files. Therefore I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/7383971) and replaced `.gitignore` body with:

```
*
!src/*
```

or

```
*
!*/src/
```

(not sure which version is correct)

However, now when I print `git status` I get only modified files from `src/` directory and no untracked files, whereas there are certainly some files from `src/` which are not yet added to git. Is is normal behaviour? If they are not recognised by `git status` how can I `git add` the new files? Or should I change somehow my "all-except" `.gitignore` version?

Comment: Can you please make a clearer point on the end result you want to reach ? For example : I don't see how to make sense of "it would probably be a lot easier for me to ignore all files except some directories/files" (which you did) and "If they are not recognised by git status how can I git add the new files?" at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

So it means, that `*` pattern excludes your `src` folder, and then you try to include some file from `src` folder - but it will not work, based on the documentation.
If you files to be included would be in root directory (on the same level as `.gitignore` file), then you could track it regardless `*` pattern.
For example, if you'd have repository like this:

[image: sample repository]

and your `.gitignore` file would be:

```
*
!D.txt
```

Then, `D.txt` file would be tracked.

So the solution to your problem will be to remove `*` pattern from `.gitigore` file; then add there each directory you'd like to ignore, and then specify files which you'd like to exclude from `.gitigore` (which you'd like to track).