# How to track only .cpp and .h files in a project using Git

Tags: git, gitignore

Here is the folders:

```
--dir  
----subdir1  
------a.h  
------a.cpp  
----subdir2  
------b.h  
------b.cpp  
----.gitignore
```

Please tell me how to track all but only `.h, .cpp, .xml`files in dir and all its subdirectories. Here is my .gitignore file:

```
*
!.gitignore
!*.cpp
!*.xml
!*.h
!*.c
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Only .gitignore can be tracked.

Comment: What if you delete the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: There are many types of files in dir and its subdirs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files). You are on the right track, but I can't understand where your .gitignore file is from your chart. If it is on the root level, you should be ok. In any case, you should find an answer in the duplicate question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+.h+.c

Answer (score 1):

The `.gitignore` file you shared will not not ignore `.cpp`, `.h`, `.c` or `.xml` files in the project's root directory. From the problem statement, it seems like you want to track these files recursively in subdirectories, which you can do using the `**` operator:

```
*
!.gitignore
!**/*.cpp
!**/*.xml
!**/*.h
!**/*.c
```