# How to ignore all files in one directory except one file?

Tags: git, github

I have a folder called `migrations` and inside that folder it has few python files which looks like this:

```
migrations/
          __init__.py
          0001_auto_20210203_1910.py
          0002_auto_20210203_1910.py
          0003_auto_20210203_1910.py
```

What I want to is to push `migrations` folder with `__init__.py` to my github and ignore other python files.

This is what i'm doing by following this question [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files):

```
migrations/*
!migrations/__init__.py
```

But it doesn't work as expected. What should I write in my .gitignore?

Thanks

Comment: What does "it doesn't work as expected" mean?

Comment: `.gitignore` only applies to untracked files. Is there any reason you can't simply ignore the `migrations` folder and add `migration/__init__.py` manually?

Comment: it commited all files inside `migrations` folder but i only want `__init__.py` to be commited

Comment: @KimhongMuong If you already _committed_ those files to your repo, modifying `.gitignore` will have no effect.

Comment: I repeat, what does "it doesn't work as expected" mean? Tell us what you do, what happens as a result, what you thought would happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure is this the best solution but i need to have 2 `.gitignore` files. One inside my root directory and another one inside `migrations` directory. All i need to put inside `migrations/.gitignore` is:

```
/*
!__init__.py
```