# Different behavior for two whitelisted nested directories in my .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

I am somewhat losing my seances right now...

I want to whitelist only certain files/folders to control vim, i3, etc

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29932318) that you might need some more lines to achieve the wanted behavior, which is to ignore all files except some specific ones, and and except files in some specific directories.

BUT
I tried it and it didn't work for `.config/i3/` and while the files in `.vim/autoload/` get included as intended (with the `.gitignore` file pictured below) that's not the case for `.config/i3/`.

Could someone explain that to me please?!

Note `.config/i3/` and `.vim/autoload/` share the same height/depth relative to the `.gitignore` file

Here is the contents of my [.gitignore file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f18yc.png):

```
/*
!/Scripts/
!/.static/
!/.config/i3/
!/.vim/autoload/

!.bashrc_extension
!.vimrc
```

The [following files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMP46.png) are found as untracked or modified in my repo -- notice `.vim/autoload` is listed but not `.config/i3`, which should also be listed:

```
.static
.vim/autoload
Scripts
.bashrc_extension
.gitignore
.vimrc
```

Comment: What precisely did you do? Paraphrasing doesn't help here, provide a [mcve]. What was the actual output? Your interpretation may be interesting, but may be caused by a flawed understanding, so the actual observations are more important.

Comment: Such a reproducable example is a small repo i guess. Ok I gonna create one.
In the mean time it would be nice if you could say more precise what you mean with "output". Gonn do my best to make that visible.

Comment: Your question has almost all that's necessary to reproduce the problem. I'm not sure a repo will help, because it's not clear that what's causing `.vim` to not be ignored (see my answer) is in the repo itself. However, in the future, please paste the contents of files as code-sample text instead of as images, it will make it a lot easier to reproduce your  setup. And, instead of an image of the files that are included, the output of `git status` on the command line, again as code-sample text, would be much easier to work with.

Comment: Losing your [seance](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/d7729eea356f1cef4fae14611fb3d73eaa3b0956/0_244_4132_2480/master/4132.jpg?width=620&quality=45&auto=format&fit=max&dpr=2&s=6e64ff0fda27c814c7431bd1fa8d675b) sounds very odd... :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Your `.gitignore` file is missing these two lines: `!.vim` and `!.config`.

#### Reproducing your problem

I have successfully reproduced half of the situation you describe. I indeed see that `.config/i3/` is not whitelisted with your `.gitignore` file, but for me `.vim/autoload` is also not whitelisted.

#### The issue: Git does not recurse into ignored directories

The problem is that once a directory is excluded by the `.gitignore` logic, Git will not recurse into it to find things inside it that might not be ignored. This is an important optimization to keep Git fast.

With `/*` in there, `.config` is ignored, so Git never even notices that `.config/i3/` exists. The solution is to add another line to say "don't ignore `.config`", so that Git will recurse into it:

```
/*
!.config
!.config/i3/
```

Now, you probably still wanted `.config/something-else` ignored, so you need one more line to do that:

```
/*
!.config
.config/*
!.config/i3
```

And now, files in `.config/` will be ignored, except those in `.config/i3/`.

You should have to do the same thing for `.vim/autoload`.

#### The `.vim/autoload` mystery

I'm not sure why your `.vim/autoload` was not ignored, but my guess would be that there is some other gitignore setting elsewhere on your filesystem, or in the parent directory, that already tells Git not to ignore `.vim`.

`git check-ignore -v <filename>` is sometimes helpful to diagnose gitignore problems, but I don't know how to make it show which exclude patterns where applied, it only shows the final ignore line that causes the file to be ignored.

However, if you run `git check-ignore -v .vim` and the output is empty, that will confirm that `.vim` is not ignored, somehow, despite your `/*` line.

#### The full solution

This is the `.gitignore` file I think you want:

```
/*

!/Scripts/
!/.static/
!/.config/
/.config/*
!/.config/i3/
!/.vim
/.vim/*
!/.vim/autoload/

!.bashrc_extension
!.vimrc
```

Comment: Thank you for all your effort joanis.
Even for the little english course^^
Still struggeling to make it work...
Most likely will delete the whole post once im done due to the quality of the question documentation
TY!

Comment: Please don't delete this post when you are done. This is a common gotcha, forgetting to whitelist the parent directory of a subdirectory you want to whitelist. I'd like to be able to link to this post in the future when the same question comes up, which I'm sure it will.