# How to add rules for gittgnore so that git ignore all types of files exept one type

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a C++ project. I want to push it on GitHub. In that project there is many types of files. But I want to have only `.cpp` files on my GitHub repository.

So, how can I set the rules for it thus only `.cpp` files upload to GitHub rather than all other files.

Comment: I think you can take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files

Comment: Please make sure you've read the gitignore documentation before ask: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Note that you'll generally also want to preserve `*.h` and/or `*.hpp` files, and often various auxiliary files such as those for a build system, data inputs, and so on. As a result, it's usually better to list the files you *don't* want; `git status` will then show (i.e., complain about as untracked) any files that you have created and have not explicitly told Git *not* to complain-about and *not* to add, which gives you a reminder as well as the opportunity to decide whether this is a "yes, do commit" or "no, do not commit" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just ignore everything: that would ignore folders as well, which means any exception (`!...`) rule would be ignored. Any folder ignored means rules applying to files inside that folder will not apply.

That is what your .gitignore must make an exception for folders first.

```
*
!.gitignore
!**/
!*.cpp

!*.h
!*.hpp
```

For a more complete gitignore: [gitignore.io](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/c++), which takes the opposite approach: only specify what you want to ignore, track everything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Except
!*.cpp
```

Comment: @SatyajitRoy you have selected the wrong answer. It only work in the current folder, not the subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading you will see that you can see the files he is uploading and then you can choose what to upload before pushing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).