# How to write .gitignore so that it only includes YAML files and some specific files?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory with the following contents:

```
.
├── .gitattributes
├── .gitignore
├── .gitignore.bak
├── coding_init.bat
├── config
│   ├── config
│   │   └── default.yml
│   └── match
│       ├── base.yml
│       └── packages
├── init.bat
├── mykey
├── packages
│   └── a.txt
├── r.bat
├── reset.bat
├── run_github.bat
└── runtime
    ├── disabledv2.ico
    ├── espanso-daemon.lock
    ├── espanso-worker.lock
    ├── espanso.lock
    ├── espanso.log
    ├── formv2.ico
    ├── icon_no_backgroundv2.png
    ├── iconv2.png
    ├── kvs
    │   ├── has_completed_wizard
    │   ├── has_displayed_welcome
    │   └── has_selected_auto_start_option
    ├── normalv2.ico
    ├── search.png
    ├── tray_explain_image.png
    └── wizardv2.ico
```

I want to create a `.gitignore` file so that only the following files are included in my commits:

- `.yml` and `.yaml` files
- `.gitattributes`
- `.gitignore`

So only these files should go into my commits:

```
.gitattributes
.gitignore
config/config/default.yml
config/match/base.yml
```

I've read the git's documentation about the `.gitignore` but I still can't make it work. I'm using `git version 2.34.0.windows.1`.
The following is what I've tried.

```
C:\test>type .gitignore
*
!*/
!*.yaml
!*.yml
!.gitignore
!.gitattributes
C:\test>git add * && git commit -m "Auto commit"
[master (root-commit) 3bfab66] Auto commit
 17 files changed, 10 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 create mode 100644 config/config/default.yml
 create mode 100644 config/match/base.yml
 create mode 100644 packages/a.txt
 create mode 100644 runtime/disabledv2.ico
 create mode 100644 runtime/espanso-daemon.lock
 create mode 100644 runtime/espanso-worker.lock
 create mode 100644 runtime/espanso.lock
 create mode 100644 runtime/espanso.log
 create mode 100644 runtime/formv2.ico
 create mode 100644 runtime/icon_no_backgroundv2.png
 create mode 100644 runtime/iconv2.png
 create mode 100644 runtime/normalv2.ico
 create mode 100644 runtime/search.png
 create mode 100644 runtime/tray_explain_image.png
 create mode 100644 runtime/wizardv2.ico

C:\test>
```

### Update

I've created a recording to show my problem.
[image]

### Update 2

```
C:\kj>type .gitignore
# Ignore everything by default
*

# Don't ignore directories (so we can look inside them, for other files)
!*/

# Don't ignore these
!*.yaml
!*.yml
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
C:\kj>
C:\kj>rm -rf .git
C:\kj>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/kj/.git/

C:\kj>git add . --dry-run
add '.gitattributes'
add '.gitignore'
add 'config/config/default.yml'
add 'config/match/base.yml'
add 'runtime/disabledv2.ico'
add 'runtime/espanso-daemon.lock'
add 'runtime/espanso-worker.lock'
add 'runtime/espanso.lock'
add 'runtime/espanso.log'
add 'runtime/formv2.ico'
add 'runtime/icon_no_backgroundv2.png'
add 'runtime/iconv2.png'
add 'runtime/normalv2.ico'
add 'runtime/search.png'
add 'runtime/tray_explain_image.png'
add 'runtime/wizardv2.ico'

C:\kj>
C:\kj>rm -rf .git
C:\kj>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/kj/.git/

C:\kj>git add \*.yml .gitattributes .gitignore --dry-run
fatal: \*.yml: '\*.yml' is outside repository at 'C:/kj'

C:\kj>git add *.yml .gitattributes .gitignore --dry-run
add '.gitattributes'
add '.gitignore'
add 'config/config/default.yml'
add 'config/match/base.yml'

C:\kj>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I've read that question. If you read carefully you will find that the .gitignore file in my question is the same as the accepted answer of that question.

Comment: Hi @danhekun, git is adding files that should be ignored because you're using a glob pattern. Instead of doing `git add *`, do `git add --all`. I updated my answer with an explanation of why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gitignore would look like this:

```
# Ignore everything by default
*

# Don't ignore directories (so we can look inside them, for other files)
!*/

# Don't ignore these
!*.yaml
!*.yml
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
```

### Don't use glob patterns here

To add untracked files automatically, use `git add --all`. DO NOT use `git add *`. This is a glob pattern. It's interpreted by your shell, not by git, and as a result it doesn't know anything about what is or isn't in the git ignore.

### What happens with a glob pattern?

The shell expands `git add *` to `git add coding_init.bat config init.bat mykey packages r.bat reset.bat run_github.bat runtime`, and from git's perspective it looks like you're saying "add these files anyway, even though I said to ignore them"

On my system, git actually detects that you're trying to add ignored files:

[image]

But this option may be off on your system.

### You don't need a glob pattern here

As stated before, `git add --all` will do what you want, and it'll only add files that aren't ignored in your `.gitignore`.

At that point, you can commit your code, as intended.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alecto, thanks for your answer! I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I uploaded a small recording in the question. Could you take a look where is the problem?

Comment: Hi @danhekun - my best guess is that git add --all works differently on windows. Could you try `git add . --dry-run`? This will recursively add files starting with the current directory, but ignoring everything in the gitignore. If that doesn't work, could you try `git add \*.yml .gitattributes .gitignore --dry-run`?

Comment: Hi @Alecto, it seems `git add *.yml .gitattributes .gitignore --dry-run` works. See my question update. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not because gratitude is hard for me, it's because I don't have enough reputation to vote

Comment: I'm happy we were able to find a solution to the problem! I wish I could have been more helpful, but I don't have a development environment set up on windows for me to test stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You have it backwards.  Your .gitignore says what to ignore.  When you have `!*.yaml` in there, you are saying to NOT ignore *.yaml files.

Get rid of the `!` and you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry for the misinterpretation. I updated my question. Actually, I need the *.yaml files in my commit.