# Easier way to not-ignore a specific deeply nested set of files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have deeply nested files that I would like to include in source control and have `git` track them.

Example is:

```
Projects/
    .git/
    StrategicProject/
        SpecificProject1/
            Method1/
                doc/
                   *.tex
    .gitignore
```

In each of the various folders there are other files/folders that I would not like to track. I only want to track, say, all of the `.tex` files in `Projects/StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/`

As of now, to accomplish this, I have in my `.gitignore` file:

```
StrategicProject/* # ignore everything under this, exceptions below
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/ # don't ignore this
StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/* # ignore everything under this, exceptions below
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/ # don't ignore this
StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/* # ignore everything under this, exceptions below
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/ # don't ignore this
StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/* # ignore everything under this, exceptions below
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/*.tex # don't ignore this
```

The above works, but is prone to error when I create a new folder structure in my working directory. It is also quite cumbersome. To track one set of `.tex` files in a nested folder needs creation of 8 lines in the `.gitignore` file. A fellow-SO user created an web-app to ease this specific difficult activity. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54870120/492307)

While that app works fine for now, it only works over the web. More generally, is there a gui app, that works offline (without having to use the internet), that can take a look at my folder structure and allows me to check/uncheck boxes (as part of its user interface) corresponding to files/folders and based on that automatically generate the appropriate `.gitignore` file?

---

ETA:

I use VSCode's default Git interface. While that does provide option to right click on a file and add it to `.gitignore`, that is not what I would like. I would like to *not* ignore a specific deeply nested set of files. I am open to trying out other editors for this task.

Comment: Could you add information about the editor that you’re using? Maybe there is an extension available for the editor.

Comment: You aren't restricted to a single `.gitignore` file. Entries in `./.gitignore` override entires in `../.gitignore`.

Comment: Or try something like `!StrategicProject/**/*.tex`.

Comment: @Tryer Could you change the title from “Easier way to create a .gitignore file” to something like “Gitignore: easier way to not-ignore a deeply nested set of files”? It seems to reflect better what specific case you meant and what people might search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one useful, albeit somewhat computationally expensive, trick you can use.  As you've seen, if you ignore a directory, Git never looks *inside* the directory, making it impossible to un-ignore files nested deeper under the directory.  This generally saves Git a lot of time: `git status` has to recursively look at everything in the working tree, *except* that every time it hits an ignored directory, it doesn't have to look at *anything* there.  Since `lstat`-ing each entity in each directory in a recursive travel of the working tree is usually *the slowest* part of a Git working-tree operation, bypassing some of these calls helps out a lot.

Still, you can prevent Git from bypassing directories at all by simply making sure that `!*/` is the *last* entry in each `.gitignore` file.  No matter where Git is in its traversal, this last entry says *if you encounter a directory, look inside it*.  Now you no longer need careful and explicit stuff like:

```
StrategicProject/*
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/
StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/*
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/
StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/*
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/
StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/*
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/*.tex
```

as you can simply list files that should be ignored; Git will always be searching everywhere.

#### A proposed future enhancement (with no implementation)

I think Git should *automatically insert* exceptions as needed.  That is, we should be able to write:

```
*.o
generated-docs
!generated-docs/*.in
```

and Git should *figure out* that this "means", e.g.:

```
generated-docs/*
!generated-docs/*.in
```

That is, the fact that we've excepted something *within* `generated-docs` means that Git should *look inside* `generated-docs`, even though the *default* is to skip over files that may be found there.

Answer (score 1):

As far as creating and maintaining the `.gitignore` you might look at plugins for your IDEs.

For example, with IntelliJ/PyCharm, this might be GUI enough for what you are trying to do:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495--ignore

Comment: The title is no longer “Easier way to create a .gitignore file” and now better reflects the problem, which is not about creating a `.gitignore` file, so you may want to delete this answer.

Comment: If you look at the feature list for this plugin, you will see: "Add a selected file/directory to Gitignore rules from the popup menu" and "Generate Gitignore rules basing on [GitHub's templates collection][github-gitignore]", so I still think this is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

For your sample by far the simplest is

```
StrategicProject/**
!StrategicProject/**/
!StrategicProject/SpecificProject1/Method1/doc/*.tex
```

which I'd pronounce "recursively exclude everything in StrategicProject but still scan all the directories for further exceptions, like these tex files".

---

Unless or until you've got a remarkably large and complicated source tree it's often more compact to put something like

```
!*/
build/
```

at the end of your `.gitignore` to simply shut off all directory exclusions except for example here any `build` directory, I'd call that idiomatic, something people who've seen it before immediately understand.