# Proper way to setup multiple .gitignore files in nested folders of a repository

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following folder structure:

```
Project/
    .git/
    .gitignore #1
    a/
        a1/
             a2.txt
             a3.txt
        .gitignore #2
    b/
        b1.txt
    c.txt
```

I would like to have `git` not ignore `a2.txt`, and not ignore entirety of `b/`. Everything else should be ignored.

Based on suggestions/comments/answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728176/easier-way-to-not-ignore-a-specific-deeply-nested-set-of-files), the content of `.gitignore #1` is:

```
a/
c.txt
```

This essentially ignores `c.txt` and everything in folder `a/`, the latter being subject to not being overridden by a deeper nested `.gitignore`.

The content of `.gitignore #2` is:

```
!a1/a2.txt
```

I was hoping this deeper nested `gitignore` file would lead to not ignoring file `a2.txt`.

However, running `git status --ignored` results in:

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        b/

Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        a/
        c.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

That is, the entirety of `a/` seems to be ignored despite the exception I was hoping would be provided by `.gitignore #2`.

How can nested `.gitignore`'s be correctly used to achieve the requirement above?

(Note: I have only named the `.gitignore` files in the description above as `#1` and `#2` for clarificatory purposes to differentiate between the two. In my actual computer, these files are properly named just `.gitignore`.)

Comment: Once you ignore folder `a/` inner `.gitignore`s under `a/` are not even consulted. Do not ignore folder `a/`.

Comment: @phd hmm...I put that in according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71728176/easier-way-to-not-ignore-a-specific-deeply-nested-set-of-files#comment126761894_71728176) comment.

Comment: @phd I removed the outermost `.gitignore`s entry of `a/`. Then, in the innermost one, I ignored everything and then made an exception of not ignoring `a2.txt`. That seems to work. I have to see what it means for an inner rule to contradict an outer rule and in doing so, is provided privileged priority over the outer rule. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule here is this:

- Git will use the OS's facilities to read directories.
- To scan a directory, Git calls [`opendir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/opendir.html) and the associated `readdir` (and eventually `closedir`) functions.
- `readdir` then returns *directory entries*, one at a time.  Each entry holds a *name component* as defined below.  Entries *may* also hold additional information—in particular the directory vs file distinction—but that's as much as Git can really count on here.  If the OS fills in a `d_type` field with `DT_DIR`, `DT_FILE`, etc., Git will try to use that, otherwise Git may have to fall back to calling `lstat` (which is expensive).

Having read the entire directory, Git now has a set of name components.  A *name component* is basically the part of a path-name that goes between slashes: for instance, with `path/to/file.ext` we have three components, `path`, `to`, and `file.ext`.  Note that the same is true for `/path/to/file.ext`: the leading slash just means "from the top" rather than "from wherever we are in the tree".  Git makes some (rather peculiar) use of this same idea—that paths starting with a slash are "root relative" and the rest are "current position relative"—when using "anchored" entries in `.gitignore` files (see below).  So if `path/to/file` exists in the top level of a working tree, Git will see only the `path` part when it scans the top level directory.

(Side note: POSIX also includes [`scandir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html), but people find this interface hard to use correctly.  It's also "more efficient" in various senses on some systems, although not always or very predictably, to use the lower level `readdir` routines, and Git uses `readdir`.)

Now that Git has the name components, Git can check them against this particular level's `.gitignore`, if it exists.  It can also combine each component with any leading path name that got Git here in the first place.  **For the initial scan** there is no such leading component, and no combining happens, but let's observe below what happens if we are allowed to proceed into `path/` (which is a directory).

The components may now need a *type* check: file vs directory.  .Real-world file systems may have additional types, including *symbolic link*, but for our purposes here *symbolic link* is to be treated like a file for the moment.  We just want to know whether component represents a directory.

Now, entries in any `.gitignore` file that we have read so far—including the one in *this* directory that we're reading now—are flagged in three independent ways:

- Some are *anchored*, as in `/path/to` or `a/b` for instance, and some are not, as in `*.o` for instance.  An *anchored* entry is one containing any slashes *after* removing a single trailing slash if it exists.
- Some are for *directories only* and some are for *all names*.  An entry is flagged as directory-only if it ends in a trailing slash.  (Since the trailing slash is meant as the "directory only" flag, it has to be ignored while deciding whether to set the "anchored" flag.)
- Some are positive ("do ignore") entries, and some are negative ("do not ignore") entries.  A negative entry is one that starts with `!` as the first character.  (An anchored negative entry for `/path` would have to read `!/path`; `/!path` does not work here.)

So let's imagine that we're reading the top level, or that we're reading directory `path` within the top level.  Let's suppose we encounter two name components at this level: `path`, and `to`.  We now check all of these things more or less at the same time (in order, so that "last entry" overrides):

- Check the *directory entry* itself against all *non-anchored* ignore expressions.  Is `path` a match for any of those?  If so, this name is ignored/unignored as per the positive/negative flag.
- Check the *full path so far* against all *anchored* ignore expressions.  For `path` this is `/path`, `/path/path`, or `/to/path`; for `to`, this is one of `/to`, or `/path/to`, or `/to/to`.  (Remember that we found both `/path` and `/to` and presumably we're looking inside both.)  If this path-so-far is a match against one of the anchored expressions, this name is ignored/unignored as per the positive/negative flag.

Note that when we *do* check an anchored path, we're looking at the full path in the working tree, while the `.gitignore` itself might be from a sub-path within the `.gitignore` tree.  So if we're reading directory `/path` for instance and we have `/path/.gitignore` and it has an anchored entry reading `/xyzzy`, we're really checking this `/xyzzy` against `/path/xyzzy` (because it's from `/path/.gitignore`, not from `/.gitignore`).  This is a little complicated, but makes sense once you think about it: the anchor is relative to the `.gitignore`'s location.  This lets you rename directories without having to edit all anchored paths in any sub-`.gitignore` files.

Note further that the "is a match" test may require that the directory entry itself name a directory.  This is the case if the *ignore* entry is flagged as directories-only.  So to check for that, we need to know if the entry—`path` or `to` for instance—names a directory in the OS's file system.

At this point, we have done all the checks we must do on *this* entry.  It either matched some `.gitignore` entry or entries, in which case the *last* matching `.gitignore` is the one taken, or it did not.  And, subdirectory `.gitignore`s are matched later in the chain, so that the *deepest* `.gitignore` that *could* match this entry will always have the *last* match, if it has a match.

If this entry did not match any `.gitignore` rule, this particular name is *not* ignored.  If it *did* match a `.gitignore` rule, the last one's positive/negative flag determines whether this particular name is ignored or not.

Now that we know if the name is ignored, we have two options, each of which has two sub-options:

- It is ignored:

  - If it's a *directory*, we simply don't scan it at all.
  - If it's a *file*, we don't auto-add the file (with `git add .` for instance), or for `git status`, we don't *complain* about the *untracked* file (assuming it is in fact untracked).
- It is not ignored:

  - If it's a *directory*, we scan it recursively and apply all these rules.
  - If it's a *file*, we `git add` it (for `git add .` for instance) or make sure to complain if it's untracked (`git status`).

This determines whether `git status` complains about it being untracked (for `git status` commands) or whether `git add` of some sort of recursive flavor (`git add --all`, `git add .`, `git add somedir`, etc.) adds it.

Note that you can override ignore entries with `git add --force`, e.g., `git add --force ignored-file` adds it even if `ignored-file` would be ignored by the normal `.gitignore` rules.  I have never tried `git add --force .` to see what happens here, but it's probably not good.  It might completely ignore all `.gitignore` rules, which seems bad, or it might completely obey them, which also seems bad.  I will leave it to the reader to try it, see what it does, and decide how bad that is.

Note also that once some pathname is in Git's index—and Git's index holds *full path names*, e.g., `path/to/file`, as a literal string with literal slashes in it—that file is *not ignored* even if it's listed in a `.gitignore` file.  The ignoring rules are specific to the recursive directory travel process, but files listed in Git's index *are* tracked and *are* checked by en-masse `git add .` operations.  Once you get past the OS-interaction stuff and into Git proper, files no longer have "containing directories", they just have long path strings with embedded forward slashes if needed.

Git's index is unable to store a bare directory name,<sup>1</sup> and that's why you cannot commit an empty directory.  The scanning process will *scan* directories for *files* and will (under appropriate conditions) add those files to the index, but it won't add the containing directory.  The closest Git gets to this is that a *submodule* entry is stored as a so-called *gitlink*, a "file" with `mode 160000`, which if it were a Linux file-system entity would be a combination of directory-and-symbolic-link (which is not allowed in the file system).  This is why the attempts to [store an empty directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-a-blank-directory-to-a-git-repository/8944077#8944077) go awry (but you can store a submodule that has no files!).

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it *can*, it just can't be stored as the kind of entry that Git uses to keep track of *files* for the next commit.  Git's index has grown a whole bunch of weird add-ons for efficiency, and that includes keeping track of untracked stuff (the so-called *untracked cache*), which includes untracked directories.  So it can't *track* a directory but it can *untrack* one!