# Git exclude everything except

Tags: git, gitignore

I know this question has been asked before but the answers didn't seem to work for me.
But seemingly there's something I don't get yet.

I initialized my home directory so as to have my configs available to clone to VMs and so on.

My .git/info/exclude looks as follows:

```
/*
!.config/nvim*
!.config/qutebrowser/*
!.config/htop/*
!.config/emacs/*
!.config/aqemu/*
!.config/dconf/*
!.vim*
!.bash*
```

### ->
git add .

Git status output:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   .bash_aliases
    new file:   .bash_helper
    new file:   .bash_history
    new file:   .bash_logout
    new file:   .bashrc
    new file:   .vim/.netrwhist
    new file:   .viminfo
    new file:   .vimrc
```

why are my .config/x/* directories not added ?
Thanks in advance and sorry if I overlooked something on the previous posts about similar topics :)

Comment: I've also tried: ```!.config/* .config/*```

Comment: Please could you give some more context? Are you planning to host your repository remotely (Github?) and then access it from your VMs?

Comment: @Ceus Once you ignore everything with `/*` you ignore all subdirectories so Git doesn't consider `!.config/*/*` for exceptions. You should unignore subdirectories; either all subdirectories with `!*/` or specific subdirectories like `!.config/`. My second advice is to prefix everything with a slash to make them match only at the root of the repo: `!/.config/`, `!/.bash*`, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/987162/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+ignore+everything+exception

Comment: So for more context; yes I am intending to host the repo on Github

Comment: I've tried to add the directory in: it now looks as follows:```
/*
!/.config/*
/.config/*
!/.config/nvim*
!/.config/qutebrowser/*
!/.config/htop/*
!/.config/emacs/*
!/.config/aqemu/*
!/.config/dconf/*
!/.vim*
!/.bash*
```
didn't work either...

Comment: Have you tried creating a .gitignore at the root of your repository with your rules in it? [gitignore documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files)

Comment: You must tell Git that it *must* scan `.config` at the top level. If you allow Git to *skip* `.config`, it will never look inside it, and never discover that `.config/foo/bar` should be added after all. The most direct way to do that is to add `!/.config` or `!/.config/` to the `.gitignore` anywhere below the first line to make it take effect.

Comment: Using `!.config/*` is NOT SUFFICIENT because Git first skips `.config` before it finds any files or subdirectories *in* `.config`.