# How can I prevent Git from ignoring a specific file in a subpath that contains bin, Win32, Release?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file that I would like to append and not ignore by Git.

But this file is located in this path: **ProjectName\Storm\bin\StormLib\Win32\ReleaseAS\StormLibRAS.lib**

The .gitignore file is located in the ProjectName folder and contains the following rules:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
[Ww][Ii][Nn]32/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]64/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Oo]ut/
[Ll]og/
[Ll]ogs/
```

I tried different combinations and searched a lot on topics. I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54870120/14425210) was more relevant for me. I reproduced this for my case.

```
*
!Storm/
Storm/*
!Storm/bin/
Storm/bin/*
!Storm/bin/StormLib/
Storm/bin/StormLib/*
!Storm/bin/StormLib/Win32/
Storm/bin/StormLib/Win32/*
!Storm/bin/StormLib/Win32/ReleaseAS/
Storm/bin/StormLib/Win32/ReleaseAS/*
!Storm/bin/StormLib/Win32/ReleaseAS/StormLibRAS.lib
```

But still no success. Moreover, in this case the Storm folder and everything inside it is ignored and removed from git.

I think all these patterns will not suit my case, so there is some kind of conflict between the git rules. I would like to remind you that the path to the file **ProjectName\Storm\bin\StormLib\Win32\ReleaseAS\StormLibRAS.lib** and the .gitignore file contains the following rules:

- [Ww][Ii][Nn]32/
- [Bb]in/
- [Rr]elease/

Perhaps this is also a problem, that these folders are in the path to the file.
If anyone has any ideas, you're welcome.

Comment: When you say "append and not ignore", do you mean that you want to have it listed as "untracked file" and keep it untracked, or do you want to track the file?

Comment: Is the directory `ProjectName` part of the tracked files, or is this just your way to say "I have a Git repository in the directory ProjectName" and `Storm` is the first level of directories?

Comment: I just wanna this specific file was on track. I should be able to do "git add -A" and then "git commit -m "Message"" and push it to remote repo.

Comment: ProjectName is just a repo folder. It contains .gitignore file, .git folder, Storm and other folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to modify your `.gitignore` file. Once a file is tracked, `.gitignore` has no effect on it. You can just

```
git add -f Storm/bin/StormLib/Win32/ReleaseAS/StormLibRAS.lib
```

to make the file tracked.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Looks like a good work around. What if someone is using an IDE (Visual Studio), they will have to manually type this command every time. Is it possible to somehow automate this by writing this command somewhere in the IDE?

Comment: This is not a workaround. It is by design. The reason why IDEs make this kind of operation hard or impossible is that it is typically outside the intended use-cases.

Comment: @Neo In VS, most binaries are hidden from your view by default, but there is an icon for "Show All Files". After clicking that you can navigate into excluded folders (like bin and obj), and then find the file you want, and right click on it and select "Git->Add ignored file to source control...". This does the same thing as presented in this answer.

Comment: @TTT You are right, thanks for the addition

Answer (score 0):

[How to Use a .gitignore File](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-gitignore-file)

This should answer your questions. As far as i understood you have to "exclude/negate" the file that you do not want to ignore (you did do that).

But I think your issue might be that you're excluding `!Storm/`
but then you're including it again `Storm/*`

I'd try to do it like this:

```
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
[Ww][Ii][Nn]32/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]/
[Aa][Rr][Mm]64/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Oo]ut/
[Ll]og/
[Ll]ogs/
!Storm\bin\StormLib\Win32\ReleaseAS\StormLibRAS.lib
```

on the bottom of your .gitignore file.

I think this will make that lib-file visible to git again

Hope this helps!