# git gitignore Adding only files that match a pattern in a subdirectory

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following directory structure for an SVN subdirectory but I prefer to work with git locally specifically by using Sourcetree.

```
.
├── Config
│   ├── Configuration
│   ├── Configuration version 2.0.zip
│   ├── DeployBuild
│   ├── Jenkinsfile
│   ├── Jenkinsfile-PublishtoSharepoint
│   └── pom.xml
├── Docker
│   ├── ...
├── GeneralRuntimeDependencies
│   └── ...
├── License
│   ├── ...
├── Platform
│   └── Branches
├── Readme.md
├── Software
│   ├── ...
├── Workspace
│   └── Servers
├── WorkspaceProjects
│   └── pom.xml
├── externals.txt
└── list.txt
```

What I want to achieve is:

1. Track all files recursively under the Config folder named:

- product.xml
- product.log.properties

2. Track all files recursively under the Platform/Branches/trunk with the following patterns:

- *.java
- Packages.xml
- *_1.0.xml

3. These are Java Maven projects so there are lots of files I am not interested in tracking. This pollutes the File status view in Sourcetree so it's hard to see what has changed or added. When my gitignore is properly set I can see just that immediately without console commands or anything. It's just there. Plus the more files Sourcetree tracks the slower it becomes.

I think that by solving the first problem I would be able to implement the solution for the second one.

This is the gitignore I am using for the first part, but I can either include everything or nothing at all but not what I actually want.

```
/*
!Config/
!Config/**
!Config/**/product.xml
!Config/**/product.log.properties
```

Edit: I'm on Mac OS.
Edit 2: I tried to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files). However, this includes punctual files or complete directories not a combination of directories with file inclusion patterns.

Comment: @mandy8055 thank you, I tested it but the Unstaged files area in the File status view is empty, I can only see my gitignore file. When I include the whole Config folder I can see all the files there, but that is not what I want.

Comment: why not add the wanted and unwanted files explicitly, you can try patterns, but that are are so may fikes/folders that it would merit the effort

Comment: @nbk Thank you for the idea, the problem is that when you add the pattern manually then you cannot see when a new file of the same type is added because you will see all the untracked files instead of the just the new files from the pattern you added. That's why I want to add using an ignore file.

Comment: git will copy aöö files that are not blocked, so if you add all zip files and what ever you need to the deny, then the rest will be copied with the new files that re not zip for example add `config/*.zip` to the list and all files taht are not zip will be copied. and if you can't get a pattern add the files manually that shouldn't be copied`config/DeployBuild`